# Customizing Bootstrap CSS template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I am just getting started with Bootstrap from Twitter and am wondering what the ‘best practices’ is for customization. I want to develop a system that will take advantage of all the power of a css template (Bootstrap or other), be completely (and easily) modifiable, be sustainable (ie – when the next version of Bootstrap is released from Twitter I don’t have to start over.

For example, I want to add background images to the top navigation. It looks like there are 3 ways to go about this:

1. Modify the .topbar classes in bootstrap.css . I don’t particularly like this because I will have lots of .topbar items and I don’t necessarily want to modify them all the same way.
2. Create new classes with my background images and apply both styles (the new and the bootstrap to my element). This may create style conflicts, which could be avoided by stripping the .topbar class into separate classes and then only using the pieces that are not stepped on by my custom class. Again this requires more work than I think should be necessary and while it is flexible, it won’t allow me to easily update bootstrap.css when Twitter releases the next installment.
3. Use variables in .LESS to achieve the customization. Offhand this seems like a good approach but having not used .LESS I have concerns about compiling css on the client and about code sustainability.

Though I am using Bootstrap, this question can be generalized to any css template.

Comment: Hi @Pabluez, yes you answered, see below. Sorry for the delay in response - I've been holiday busy.

Comment: I believe this article will help you http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2014/6/blog_template_using_bootstrap3_part2

Comment: This thread is informative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The best thing to do is.

**1. fork twitter-bootstrap from github and clone locally.**

they are changing really quickly the library/framework (they diverge internally. Some prefer library, i'd say that it's a framework, because change your layout from the time you load it on your page). Well... forking/cloning will let you fetch the new upcoming versions easily.

**2. Do not modify the bootstrap.css file**

It's gonna complicate your life when you need to upgrade bootstrap (and you will need to do it).

**3. Create your own css file and overwrite whenever you want original bootstrap stuff**

if they set a topbar with, let's say, `color: black;` but you wan it white, create a new very specific selector for this topbar and use this rule on the specific topbar. For a table for example, it would be `<table class="zebra-striped mycustomclass">`. If you declare your css file after `bootstrap.css`, this will overwrite whatever you want to.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Just to add onto his 3rd point: you can either create a new class to apply in addition to the old class, or just overwrite/add the properties you want to change.

Comment: that was what i meant with mycustomcss... i'm gonna edit it to mycustomclass, besides zebra-striped (bootstrap-class)

Comment: is there aything you can add to this as to how to do this the "new" less/sass way?  ie:  how can you subclass a "bootstrap" style?  inherit all + augment.  i've yet to get my head around whether this is a mix-in, and extend, or a ??  sorry to be dumb.

Comment: +1Thanks for the answer.  I have been doing this, and it works but it just doesn't feel like the most sustainable answer.  If I get an updated bootstrap.css file, I may have to change my custom override classes to adapt to any changes.  Like @alexgray, I would like to understand a way to do this with less or mixins. Or, even better a way to create a sandbox with no bootstrap applied so I can use my styles without having to override bootstrap.  If anyone has a good tutorial out there, pass it along

Comment: Here's to hoping we can come up with a better alternative some day.

Comment: The problem I have with this issue is that is you want to apply your customizations to a new project, then you have to go through your HTML and add all of the selectors.

Comment: You could add a prefix to all your selectors so whenever you had to update the framework you could easily find files you've modified with your own styles.

Comment: Please see my suggestion below, taken from the Bootstrap docs -- I think that achieves what you're trying to do here (using Less in a clean way, without other external dependencies).

Comment: What's the point of forking Bootstrap if you're only going to add alterations to your own CSS file?

Answer (score 43):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

As explained in the Bootstrap docs, [modifying the existing "theme" colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#modify-map) is done using SASS. As with prior versions, you can also override the Bootstrap CSS by adding CSS rules that follow after the `bootstrap.css` and use the correct CSS specificity.

[Bootstrap 5 - change theme colors](https://codeply.com/p/sCHE6yUjHT)

**Bootstrap 4**

I'm revisiting this Bootstrap customization question for 4.x, which now utilizes [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) instead of LESS. In general, there are 2 ways to customize Bootstrap...

**1. Simple CSS Overrides**

One way to customize is simply using CSS to override Bootstrap CSS. For maintainability, CSS customizations are put in a separate `custom.css` file, so that the `bootstrap.css` remains unmodified. The reference to the `custom.css` follows *after* the `bootstrap.css` for the overrides to work...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
```

Just add whatever changes are needed in the custom CSS. For example...

```
    /* remove rounding from cards, buttons and inputs */
    .card, .btn, .form-control {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
```

Before (`bootstrap.css`)

[image]

After (with `custom.css`)

[image]

When making customizations, you should understand [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Overrides in the `custom.css` need to use selectors that are the same specificity as (or more specific) the `bootstrap.css`.

> Note there is no need to use `!important` in the custom CSS, unless
> you're overriding one of the [Bootstrap Utility
> classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities). [CSS
> specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
> always works for one CSS class to override another.

---

**2. Customize using SASS**

If you're familiar with [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) (and you should be to use this method), you can customize Bootstrap with your own `custom.scss`. There is a [section in the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/) that explains this, however the docs *don't explain* how to utilize existing variables in your `custom.scss`. For example, let's change the body background-color to `#eeeeee`, and **change/override** the blue `primary` contextual  color to [Bootstrap's `$purple` variable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#color)...

```
/* custom.scss */    

/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

/* -------begin customization-------- */   

/* simply assign the value */ 
$body-bg: #eeeeee;

/* use a variable to override primary */
$theme-colors: (
  primary: $purple
);
/* -------end customization-------- */  

/* finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes! */
@import "bootstrap";
```

This also works to **create new custom classes**. For example, here I add `purple` to the theme colors which creates *all* the CSS for `btn-purple`, `text-purple`, `bg-purple`, `alert-purple`, etc...

```
/* add a new purple custom color */
$theme-colors: (
  purple: $purple
);
```

https://codeply.com/go/7XonykXFvP

With SASS you must **@import bootstrap *after* the customizations** to make them work! Once the SASS is compiled to CSS (**this must be done using a SASS compiler node-sass, gulp-sass, npm webpack, etc..**), the resulting CSS is the customized Bootstrap. If you're *not* familiar with SASS, you can customize Bootstrap using a tool like this [theme builder](https://themestr.app/) I created.

**[Custom Bootstrap Demo (SASS)](https://codeply.com/go/lobGxGgfZE)**

Note: Unlike 3.x, Bootstrap 4.x doesn't offer an *official* customizer tool. You can however, download the [**grid only** CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/contents/#css-files) or use another [4.x custom build tool](https://themestr.app/customize) to re-build the Bootstrap 4 CSS as desired.

---

Related: 
[How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070142/171456)
[How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)
[How to create new set of color styles in Bootstrap 4 with sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382588/)
[How to Customize Bootstrap](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203)

Comment: Noice - how about setting a custom color for background, border, font for the new custom button?

Comment: Is it normal that the generated CSS file is about 160 Kb (compressed 130Kb)? Is it possible just to override a primary color, for instance?

Comment: Note: Remember to use the Autoprefixer after compilation

Answer (score 20):

I think the officially preferred way is now to use Less, and either dynamically override the bootstrap.css (using less.js), or recompile bootstrap.css (using Node or the Less compiler).

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.4/docs/less.html), here's how to override bootstrap.css styles dynamically:

> Download the latest Less.js and include the path to it (and Bootstrap) in the `<head>`.
>
> ```
>  <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/path/to/bootstrap.less">
>     <script src="/path/to/less.js"></script>
> ```
>
> To recompile the .less files, just save them and reload your page. Less.js compiles them and stores them in local storage.

Or if you prefer to statically compile a new bootstrap.css with your custom styles (for production environments):

> Install the LESS command line tool via Node and run the following command:
>
> ```
> $ lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css
> ```

Comment: this is the prefered way :)

Answer (score 10):

Since Pabluez's answer back in December, there is now a better way to customize Bootstrap.

Use: [Bootswatch](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch) to generate your bootstrap.css

Bootswatch builds the normal Twitter Bootstrap from the latest version (whatever you install in the bootstrap directory), but also imports your customizations. This makes it easy to use the the latest version of Bootstrap, while maintaining custom CSS, without having to change anything about your HTML. You can simply sway boostrap.css files.

Comment: could you elaborate on best way to use this. I downloaded bootswatch and built my css using grunt swatch:theme but I'm still puzzled about which files I should put where. I'm trying to get to a situation where I can download an updated version of bootstrap or a bootswatch theme and use it, but still use my customized variables. (I'm working in VisualStudio2013 Pro if that makes a difference). I don't want to use javascript to do compilation. For now, I'm OK with running a build command. Later, I'll try and find a good method to automate. Thanks Mark

Answer (score 5):

You can use the bootstrap template from

http://www.initializr.com/

which includes all the bootstrap .less files. You can then change variables / update the less files as you want and it will automatically compile the css. When deploying compile the less file to css.

Answer (score 3):

The best option in my opinion is to compile a custom LESS file including bootstrap.less, a custom variables.less file and your own rules :

1. Clone bootstrap in your root folder : `git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git`
2. Rename it "bootstrap"
3. Create a package.json file : https://gist.github.com/jide/8440609
4. Create a Gruntfile.js : https://gist.github.com/jide/8440502
5. Create a "less" folder
6. Copy bootstrap/less/variables.less into the "less" folder
7. Change the font path : `@icon-font-path: "../bootstrap/fonts/";`
8. Create a custom style.less file in the "less" folder which imports bootstrap.less and your custom variables.less file : https://gist.github.com/jide/8440619
9. Run `npm install`
10. Run `grunt watch`

Now you can modify the variables any way you want, override bootstrap rules in your custom style.less file, and if some day you want to update bootstrap, you can replace the whole bootstrap folder !

EDIT: I created a Bootstrap boilerplate using this technique : https://github.com/jide/bootstrap-boilerplate

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote a [post](http://betaorbust.com/maintainable-bootstrap-customization/) about how I've been doing it at [Udacity](https://udcity.com) for the last couple years. This method has meant we've been able to update Bootstrap whenever we wanted to without having merge conflicts, thrown out work, etc. etc.

The post goes more in depth with examples, but the basic idea is:

- Keep a pristine copy of bootstrap and overwrite it externally.
- Modify one file (bootstrap's variables.less) to include your own variables.
- Make your site file @include bootstrap.less and then your overrides.

This does mean using LESS, and compiling it down to CSS before shipping it to the client (client-side LESS if finicky, and I generally avoid it) but it is EXTREMELY good for maintainability/upgradability, and getting LESS compilation is really really easy. The linked github code has an example using grunt, but there are many ways to achieve this -- even GUIs if that's your thing.

Using this solution, your example problem would look like:

- Change the nav bar color with @navbar-inverse-bg in your variables.less (not bootstrap's)
- Add your own nav bar styles to your bootstrap_overrides.less, overwriting anything you need to as you go.
- Happiness.

When it comes time to upgrade your bootstrap, you just swap out the pristine bootstrap copy and everything will still work (if bootstrap makes breaking changes, you'll need to update your overrides, but you'd have to do that anyway)

Blog post with walk-through is [here](http://betaorbust.com/maintainable-bootstrap-customization/).

Code example on github is [here](https://github.com/betaorbust/overstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Use LESS with Bootstrap...

[Here are the Bootstrap docs for how to use LESS](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.4/docs/less.html)

(they have moved since previous answers)

Comment: If the documents have moved, edit the other answers to reflect that

Comment: Ironically, the link in this answer is dead.

Answer (score 0):

you can start with this tool, https://themestr.app/theme , seeing how it overwrites the scss variables, you would get an idea what variable impacts what. its the simplest way I think.

example scss genearation:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,700);
$font-family-base:Montserrat;
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:200,300,400,700);
$headings-font-family:Open Sans;

$enable-grid-classes:false;
$primary:#222222;
$secondary:#666666;
$success:#333333;
$danger:#434343;
$info:#515151;
$warning:#5f5f5f;
$light:#eceeec;
$dark:#111111;
@import "bootstrap";
```