# Alternatives to Bootstrap for Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I plan to build my own site and launch soon. I am doing all the coding using Rails Framework. I am aware of Bootstrap for Styling of my site.

However, I have already used Bootstrap for another site in the past. Please suggest some other alternatives.

Thanks
- Sid

Answer (score 9):

[Zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) would be my choice if I were to use something other than Twitter Bootstrap.

If I wanted to go really minimalist I'd use [thoughtbot's bourbon](http://thoughtbot.com/bourbon/)

Some others: [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) and [HTML Kickstart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/), if you're looking for something really light.

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to apply different styling** to your websites and you achieve this by switching to different css front-end frameworks you're **going to have a tough time** after a few websites.  You will not only have to learn how to use these frameworks every time, but also after a few websites you're going to run out of frameworks to try out.

Instead, why not **work out how to customize Bootstrap** such that you can make it look unique (I know that Bootstrap out of the box is becoming ubiquitous and it's nice to look different).

There are [some nice ideas here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template) about customizing Bootstrap and [there are other resources](http://rubysource.com/how-to-customize-twitter-bootstrap%E2%80%99s-design-in-a-rails-app/) out there too if you look for them.

Get good at using one front-end framework and understand how to customize it and you'll be a more productive developer as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [RailsThemes](http://railsthemes.com) for Ruby on Rails designs that are an alternative to using Bootstrap. The themes should work after installation without needing to convert your site to use Bootstrap's markup. Several common gems just work out of the box. Some of the themes use Skeleton, agreeing with Dty's answer. (Full disclosure: I am part of the team working on RailsThemes.)

Answer (score 2):

I know that you do not want to use Bootstrap again for another site, but would suggest that you have a look at this website. They use Twitter Bootstrap, but some of the themes may inspire you to different looks and feels of Bootstrap. The typical out of the box configuration of bootstrap does look very similar to many sites, but these guys have done a great job of taking the basic look and making them look real classy.

https://wrapbootstrap.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something new, you can try semantic ui: http://semantic-ui.com/

The code is meant to be very readeable. For example:

**Semantic:**

```
<div class="ui three column grid">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">3</div>
</div>
```