# Using Bootstrap's WTF Quick Forms without its CSS

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm writing a web app with Flask and I've made a CSS template that I'm happy with. I want to use the `wtf.quick_form()` feature from Bootstrap, but I can't load Bootstrap without overriding my own CSS. All I want to do is load the `quick_form()` feature. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template) that covers the topic of using custom CSS, but, honestly, if you're only wanting to use Bootstrap for `quick_form()`, you don't have to go through all of that.

Let's say you have your **base.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
```

It's suggested elsewhere that you load your `'style.css'` file *after* you load the `'bootstrap.css'` file, but you can get away with a simple `link rel` to `'style'.css'` if all you want to do is load `quick.form()`. Just make sure you remember to import `"bootstrap/wtf.html"` in your base template or in the template file that you want to use `quick_form()`.

Comment: I followed your example but when I tried to render a form in my template, I got a Jinja Build Error -- it didn't recognize `wtf.quick_form()`.

Comment: Did you make sure to import "bootstrap/wtf.html" OR make sure that the template page that you're editing extends your base page file? Also, post the specific error so we have more to work with.

Comment: I went back and saw that I hadn't extended my template. I did that and now I've got quick_forms()! Thanks!