# How to change btn color in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to change all `.btn` properties in Bootstrap? I have tried below ones, but still sometimes it shows the default blue color (say after clicking and removing the mouse etc). How can I change the entire theme altogether?

```
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited {
    background-color: #8064A2;
}
```

Comment: You can simply create override_default.css and include it at immediate next line to bootstrap library css, and then you are free to override anything.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The easiest way to see which properties you need to override is to take a look at [Bootstrap's source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/), specifically the `.button-variant` mixin defined in [mixins/buttons.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/buttons.less). You still need to override quite a lot of properties to get rid of all of the `.btn-primary` styling (e.g. `:focus`, `disabled`, usage in dropdowns etc).

A better way might be to:

1. Create your own customized version of Bootstrap using [Bootstrap's online customization tool](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
2. Manually create your own color class, e.g. `.btn-whatever`
3. Use a LESS compiler and use the `.button-variant` mixin to create your own color class, e.g. `.btn-whatever`

Comment: I too think that creating a customized version of Bootstrap should be the ideal way to go about this, as there might be a lot of properties to change. Thanks.

Comment: in step 3 - I try to create LESS  mixin on using .btn-primary, but :hover is not working. How should I mixing the hover state?

Answer (score 149):

If you want to override any default properties in Bootstrap you have to make the properties as important.

```
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited {
    background-color: #8064A2 !important;
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: The `!important` was the key!

Comment: That's not a good way to modify Bootstrap, the changes should be done via Less or Sass variables when building your own custom Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: If you just link to bootstrap before you link to your custom style sheet then your custom style sheet will take precedence.

Comment: I will add to this DO THIS AS A LAST RESORT!!!  Add in a SASS compilation to your site.  Create a cutsom.sass file and import bootstrap.  Then override according to the bootstrap docs.  

If you don't want to learn how to do that, then yeah, you can override that way. :-)

Answer (score 116):

### **Using `!important` is [NOT the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)**

A better option is to use SASS to regenerate the `btn-*` CSS classes as desired using the appropriate SASS mixins...

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2023)**

Bootstrap 5 has the same `button-variant` and `button-outline-variant` SASS mixins which can be used to customize the button color after bootstrap is imported...

```
/* import the Bootstrap */
@import "bootstrap";

/* ------- customize primary button color -------- */   
$mynewcolor:#77cccc;

.btn-primary {
    @include button-variant($mynewcolor, darken($mynewcolor, 7.5%), darken($mynewcolor, 10%), lighten($mynewcolor,5%), lighten($mynewcolor, 10%), darken($mynewcolor,30%));
}

.btn-outline-primary {
    @include button-outline-variant($mynewcolor, #222222, lighten($mynewcolor,5%), $mynewcolor);
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/UNvB5hRsfF

---

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2019)**

Now that Bootstrap 4 uses SASS, you can easily **change the primary button color** using the `button-variant` mixins:

```
$mynewcolor:#77cccc;

.btn-primary {
    @include button-variant($mynewcolor, darken($mynewcolor, 7.5%), darken($mynewcolor, 10%), lighten($mynewcolor,5%), lighten($mynewcolor, 10%), darken($mynewcolor,30%));
}
    
.btn-outline-primary {
    @include button-outline-variant($mynewcolor, #222222, lighten($mynewcolor,5%), $mynewcolor);
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/JnV3xDDiaH (**SASS demo**)

This SASS compiles into the following CSS...

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #7cc;
    border-color: #5bc2c2
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #52bebe;
    border-color: #8ad3d3
}

.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(91, 194, 194, 0.5)
}

.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary:disabled {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #7cc;
    border-color: #5bc2c2
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #9cdada;
    border-color: #2e7c7c
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(91, 194, 194, 0.5)
}

.btn-outline-primary {
    color: #7cc;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #7cc
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover {
    color: #222;
    background-color: #8ad3d3;
    border-color: #7cc
}

.btn-outline-primary:focus,
.btn-outline-primary.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(119, 204, 204, 0.5)
}

.btn-outline-primary.disabled,
.btn-outline-primary:disabled {
    color: #7cc;
    background-color: transparent
}

.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.show>.btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #8ad3d3;
    border-color: #7cc
}

.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.show>.btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(119, 204, 204, 0.5)
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/lD3tUE01lo (**CSS demo**)

---

To change the primary color for *all* classes see: [Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template) and [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)

Comment: This post helped me in creating a purple button as seen in the home page of Bootstrap.

Comment: And for the slow witted like me, note that you need to do the overriding AFTER you import bootstrap itself, because that import contains the stuff you're about to include.and re-define.

Comment: How to import that bootstrap?

Comment: For a long time, I was using !important. Not any more!

Comment: `button-variant` requires only 2 arguments - `background` and `border` - rest is optional/autogenerated, I also like to specify the color explicitly so this is enough: `@include button-variant($bg, darken($bg, 7.5%), $textColor);` :-)

Answer (score 39):

I guess you forgot `.btn-primary:focus` property and comma after `.btn-primary`
You also can use less and redefine some colors in variables.less file
With this in mind your code will be look like this:

```css
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited,
.btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #8064A2;
    border-color: #8064A2;
}
```

Comment: Then there's border color, which still remains blue. I guess less is the way to go for this, right?

Comment: You can redefine border as well.

Comment: I also had to change the background image before it changed color: `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#8064A2 0,#8064A2 100%);` or `background-image: none;`.

Answer (score 17):

Just create your own button on:

- http://blog.koalite.com/bbg/
- add the CSS at the end off your boottrap.min.css

Cheers

Comment: This is nice and simple

Answer (score 10):

The **simplest** way is to:

1. intercept every button state
2. add `!important` to override the states

```
    .btn-primary:hover,
    .btn-primary:active,
    .btn-primary:visited,
    .btn-primary:focus {
      background-color: black !important;
      border-color: black !important;
    }
```

---

**OR** the more **practical** UI way is to make the hover state of the button darker than the original state. Just use the CSS snippet below:

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: Blue !important;
  border-color: Blue !important;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited,
.btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: DarkBlue !important;
  border-color: DarkBlue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Remove the button color class like "btn-success" and put a custom class like "btn-custom" and write css for that class. That simply works for me.

```
HTML :

<button class="btn btn-block login " type="submit">Sign In</button>

CSS:

 .login  {
    background-color: #0057fc;
    color: white;   
}
```

Comment: With this, you lose e.g. hover behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of complex and lengthy CSS here when all you need is this if you want to cover the whole button with one color including the button border:

```
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited {
        background-color: #D64B8A !important;
        border-color: #D64B8A !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You have missed one style ".btn-primary:active:focus" which causes that still during btn click default bootstrap color show up for a second.
This works in my code:

```
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active:focus {
background-color: #8064A2;}
```

Comment: You saw the problem others didn't, but this doesn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my flavor without the loss of hover. I personally like it better than the standard bootstrap transitioning.

```css
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited {
  background-color: #8064A2 !important;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #594671 !important;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-primary">Hover me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a step-by-step guide to @Codeply-er's answer above for SASS/SCSS newbies like me.

1. Save `btnCustom.scss`.

```
/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import 'bootstrap';

/* Define color */
$mynewcolor:#77cccc;

.btn-custom {
    @include button-variant($mynewcolor, darken($mynewcolor, 7.5%), darken($mynewcolor, 10%), lighten($mynewcolor,5%), lighten($mynewcolor, 10%), darken($mynewcolor,30%));
}

.btn-outline-custom {
    @include button-outline-variant($mynewcolor, #222222, lighten($mynewcolor,5%), $mynewcolor);
}
```

2. Download a SASS compiler such as [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) so that SCSS file above can be compiled to CSS.
3. Clone the [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) github repo because the compiler needs the button-variant mixins somewhere.
4. Explicitly import bootstrap functions by creating a `_bootstrap.scss` file as below. This will allow the compiler to access the Bootstrap functions and variables.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

5. Compile `btnCustom.scss` with the previously downloaded compiler to css.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I was looking for! I've been wasting time trying to figure out which files I should import, cause I was getting undefined variables errors all the time! 
Just want to note that I had to import two more files (Bootstrap 5.3.2):
import "../scss/_variables-dark.scss";
import "../scss/_maps.scss";

Answer (score 2):

I had run into the similar problem recently, and managed to fix it with adding classes

```
  body .btn-primary {
    background-color: #7bc143;
    border-color: #7bc143;
    color: #FFF; }
    body .btn-primary:hover, body .btn-primary:focus {
      border-color: #6fb03a;
      background-color: #6fb03a;
      color: #FFF; }
    body .btn-primary:active, body .btn-primary:visited, body .btn-primary:active:focus, body .btn-primary:active:hover {
      border-color: #639d34;
      background-color: #639d34;
      color: #FFF; }
```

Also pay attention to [disabled] and [disabled]:hover, if this class is used on input[type=submit]. Like this:

```
body .btn-primary[disabled], body .btn-primary[disabled]:hover {
  background-color: #7bc143;
  border-color: #7bc143; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom colors using [bootstrap theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/) in your config file for example `variables.scss` and make sure you import that file before bootstrap when compiling.

```
$theme-colors: (
    "whatever": #900
);
```

Now you can do `.btn-whatever`

Answer (score 2):

As of Bootstrap 5, the right way to do this is to simply override the `$primary` theme colour:

Simply add the following to your Bootstrap overrides file (ie: could be named 'Core.scss' for example:

```
//
// Bootstrap
//
// overrides
$primary: /*new colour*/orange;
```

Here is the official docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#modify-map

Answer (score 0):

I think using `!important` is not a very wise option. It may cause for many other issues specially when making the site responsive. So, my understanding is that, the best way to do this to use custom button CSS class with `.btn` bootstrap class. `.btn` is the base style class for bootstrap button. So, keep that as the layout, we can change other styles using our custom css class. 
One more extra thing I want to mention here. Some people are trying to remove blue outline from the buttons. It's not a good idea because that accessibility issue when using keyboard. Change it's color using `outline-color:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the OP of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249541/change-arrow-colors-in-bootstraps-carousel) but it helped me so:

I wanted to change the color of the next/previous buttons of the bootstrap carousel on my homepage.

**Solution:**
Copy the selector names from bootstrap.css and move them to your own style.css  (with your own prefrences..) :

```css
.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: black;
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: none;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon:after
{
  content: '>';
  font-size: 55px;
  color: red;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
  content: '<';
  font-size: 55px;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my participation for the "outline" button:

Replace `#8e5b5b` with your color and `#b3a7a7` by your color but usually more bright.

```css
.btn-outline-custom{
  color: #8e5b5b;
  border-color: #8e5b5b;
}

.btn-outline-custom:focus{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #b3a7a7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #b3a7a7;
  outline: 0;
}

.btn-outline-custom:hover,
.btn-outline-custom:active{
  color: #fff;
    background-color: #8e5b5b;
    border-color: #8e5b5b;
}
```