# How to modify bootstrap 4's primary color?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 alpha-6,I want to modify bootstrap 4's primary color(#0275d8),is there a variable that can set the value?

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the relevant css styles with your own custom styles, otherwise it might be worth it to look into using Less. Less is a CSS Preprocessor that allows you to store variables used in your css such as color values. You can see an example of this below:

```
@brand-primary: darken(#428bca, 6.5%); // #337ab7
@brand-success: #5cb85c;
@brand-info:    #5bc0de;
@brand-warning: #f0ad4e;
@brand-danger:  #d9534f;

.masthead {
  background-color: @brand-primary;
}
```

You can read more on bootstraps use of Less [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less)

Answer (score -1):

**Update 2019 Bootstrap 4**

It's easily done with SASS. Just set the <s>`$brand-primary`</s> `$primary` variable.

```
$primary: hotpink;
```

[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/vuKU32KeIi/bootstrap-4-change-color)

---

See: [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)

Comment: In Bootstrap v4. It's been changed to the `$primary` variable. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/scss/_variables.scss