# Extending Bootstrap 4 and SASS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

As Bootstrap was only recently officially released some of the pages still need to be worked on ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/ - **todo: this entire page**).

I'm entirely new to sass/scss so this might be easy. What I want to do is create an entire class that works with all the pre-configured styles in bootstrap.

For example, how could I make a *.drop-shadow* class, that would implement all the colors (and eventually other settings) like *.drop-shadow-primary*, *.drop-shadow-secondary* and so on.

Comment: A place to start: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done by iterating the Bootstrap 4 `theme-colors()` map like this...

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .drop-shadow-#{$color} {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px $value;
  }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/LyLcAK9oHN

Also see: [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color/50253707#50253707)