# How to use bootstrap color variable in SASS

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

It's bootstrap 4-beta in `SASS`.

The question is how I can use the bootstrap color variable in my SASS application? What I have done to do this is:

```
color: $theme-colors(primary);
```

but this doesn't work and throws an error.

any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You should use this: `color: theme-color("primary");`

Theme colors isn't a variable, it is a function, that's why you shouldn't use `$` before it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use...

```
color: $primary;
```

Bootstrap assigns values to the color values before adding them to the theme-colors so they're all available in the `variables.scss`.

Also see: [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)

Comment: Yep, this method is simpler than using the function/mixin!

Comment: This gives me a different color than the one defined in my theme-colors as primary. The answer below works: `color: theme-color("primary");`