# How to change the background-color in page-wrapper?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how can I replace (Just make a new .css, replacing an id/class) the css in some parts of bootstrap? I want to change the background-color for page-wrapper, by default is white.

Comment: Make your own css and use `body { backgroud-color: #123456; }`.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are linking to your new /.css file underneath bootstraps css in your head.

then reference the class you would like to change styles on inside your new /.css file.

```css
.page-wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: will be replaced all the page-wrapper, or just the background-color?

Comment: it will add a background color to every element with the class of .page-wrapper