# Modify a Bootstrap variable within a mixin

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

Using Bootstrap 4, I'm trying the change the value of `brand-primary` in a mixin:

```
// variables
$theme-colors: (
  "main": #9fa28b,
  "another-section": #ec008c,
  "yet-another-section": #00b0d8
);

// main scss
@mixin theme($color){
    $theme-colors: (
        "brand-primary": $color
    );
}

body {
    @include theme(theme-color($key: "main"));

    &.another-section {
        @include theme(theme-color($key: "another-section"));
    }

    &.yet-another-section {
        @include theme(theme-color($key: "yet-another-section"));
    }
}
```

This compiles without an error but nothing with the classes `another-section` or `yet-another-section` are in the compiled css.

Is there a way of overriding `brand-primary` within a mixin (or any variable)?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you attempting to modify? There is no `brand-primary` variable in Bootstrap 4? It's just `primary`?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct you want to change the color. All you have to  do is override primary color check this link [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#advanced-variable-functions

use map.get($theme-colors, "warning"); instead!