# how to @extend bootstrap classes using customized colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, node-sass

Hi Stackoverflow Fans,

how can I @extend bootstrap classes using customized colors  ?

Firstly, I created my customised colors in my custom-bootstrap.scss:

```
$theme-colors: (
  'primary': #3b86ff,
  'secondary': #6c757d,
  'success': #28a745,
  'error': #dc3545,
  'white': #FFFFFF,
  // Neutrals
  'grey-0': #f9f9fa,
  'grey-1': #eceef0,
  'grey-2': #dee1e5,
  'grey-3': #cfd3da,
  'grey-4': #bfc4cd,
  'grey-5': #adb3bf,
  'grey-6': #98a0ae,
  'grey-7': #828a97,
  'grey-8': #666d77,
  'grey-9': #3c3f46
);
```

Now I want to create some customized classes based on (that extends) Bootstrap classes. For example:

**The class below compiles and works**

```
.my-info-card {
  @extend .card, .bg-light, .border, .bg-secondary, .text-dark;
}
```

**The class below does NOT compile**

```
.my-info-card2 {
 @extend .card, .border-gray-5, .m-3, .mt-2;
}
```

I get a compilation error:

SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .border-gray-5 !optional" to avoid this error.
╷
130 │   @extend .card, .border-gray-5, .m-3, .mt-2;
│   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The code below works as expected, but I want replace the css class by **my-info-card2**:

```
<div class="card border-gray-5 m-3 mt-2">
```

Comment: Are you `@import`ing the custom variables file?

Comment: where is `border-gray-5` defined?

Comment: @nschonni I am customizing the bootstrap 4.1 I am doing everything right. See here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/

Comment: @Zim  ```border-gray-5``` is automatically created by Bootstrap because I defined the color ```gray-5``` in the ```$theme-colors```. Bootstrap does the rest in its thousand scss files when it is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `border-grey-5` not `border-gray-5`. This is how you would create a new theme color named `grey-5` and extend one of the generated classes:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #7400d9,
  "grey-5": #adb3bf,
);

.my-info-card2 {
   @extend .card, .border-grey-5, .m-3, .mt-2;
}
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/a2bcQsBaPH)

Also see:
[How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass)
[How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)