# Bootstrap - Sass manipulation

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I am new to sass in general but have been trying to customize my bootstrap more. All I want to do is simply change the theme colors.

I have my main.scss folder importing the bootstrap and then I use a live watch extension into my main.css folder. As far as I am aware I have everything set up correctly. But when I simply try to change the theme colors in my scss file with

```
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #0000, (random color here)
);
```

it doesn't change the color. In fact, all it does is get rid of every single place where I have used the primary color on my webpage. Not only this, but it turns all other colors to gray for whatever reason. I am completely stuck here, does anyone have any suggestions that can help? I have tried searching all over for any explanations but have not been able to locate any at this moment.

Comment: Can you check this question? I think the first answer of this question can solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have seen that thread and unfortunately trying all options in there have not helped. I have even tried importing the variable before changing the theme colors with bootstrap being imported after that but it still doesn't work. Even simply typing theme-colors without editing any of them breaks all of my color. It is very strange!