# How to change the color of contextual color classes in boostrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Boostrap 5 in my project and I am using elements with classes like btn-primary, text-success, etc.
In Boostrap the -primary class is represented with blue, -success is represented with green and so on. I need to be able to change the default color of those classes. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)

Comment: I have no knowledge of sass. Could you give me some indications of how to do it?

Comment: Override the CSS vars. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/css-variables/

Answer (score 1):

If you want overwrite the bootstrap color theme, follow below steps:

1. Create your own SCSS file ("project.scss": use this file in your project).
2. Define the color which you want to change (code is give below).
3. Import the bootstrap SCSS file.

```
    $primary: #3b0175;
    $danger: #c40000;
    
    @import "bootstrap";
```