# how to change bootstrap version 4 button color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I can change the primary button color by changing the theme-color in bootstrap v4. But it affects all other components as well.
How to set the primary button colour without affecting the theme color?
I dont want to set brand-primary and achieve it.Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**2019 Update for Bootstrap 4.1+**

Now that Bootstrap 4 uses SASS, you can easily **change only the button color** using the `button-variant` mixins. Since you only want to change the primary button color, and not the entire primary theme color, you need to use the `button-variant` mixins in SASS. You can set whatever `$mynewcolor` and/or `lighten()` and `darken()` percentages you'd like.

```
$mynewcolor:teal;

.btn-primary {
    @include button-variant($mynewcolor, darken($mynewcolor, 7.5%), darken($mynewcolor, 10%), lighten($mynewcolor,5%), lighten($mynewcolor, 10%), darken($mynewcolor,30%));
}

.btn-outline-primary {
    @include button-outline-variant($mynewcolor, #222222, lighten($mynewcolor,5%), $mynewcolor);
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/f3uTwmsCVZ (**SASS demo**)

This SASS compiles into the following CSS...

```
.btn-primary{color:#fff;background-color:teal;border-color:#005a5a}

.btn-primary:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#004d4d;border-color:#009a9a}
.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary.focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,90,90,0.5)}
.btn-primary.disabled,.btn-primary:disabled{color:#fff;background-color:teal;border-color:#005a5a}
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle{color:#fff;background-color:#00b3b3;border-color:#000}
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,90,90,0.5)}

.btn-outline-primary{color:teal;background-color:transparent;background-image:none;border-color:teal}.btn-outline-primary:hover{color:#222;background-color:#009a9a;border-color:teal}
.btn-outline-primary:focus,.btn-outline-primary.focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,128,128,0.5)}
.btn-outline-primary.disabled,.btn-outline-primary:disabled{color:teal;background-color:transparent}
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.show>.btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle{color:#fff;background-color:#009a9a;border-color:teal}
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.show>.btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,128,128,0.5)}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/l9UGO7J6V1 (**CSS demo**)

---

To change the primary color for *all* contextual classes (bg-primary, alert-primary, etc..) see: [Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template) and [How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color)

Also see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50973207/171456
[How to theme bootstrap](https://medium.com/wdstack/a-custom-bootstrap-theme-builder-8ca3f38733f7)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it covers all button states.

Comment: To note that one can't have a font colour separate from the background colour, which is disappointing.

Comment: @nicodemus13 you mean you can't using the button-variant mixin?

Comment: Yes, sorry, wasn't clear. The font colour is calculated from the background colour.

Comment: The arguments are `button-variant(background, border-color, hover:background-color, hover:background-color, active:background-color, active:background-color)`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Then I added the above code **after** my `@import ../scss/bootstrap.scss` and it works!

Comment: This didn't cover the case where the button was focused and I hovered out.

Answer (score 14):

You can add custom color or redefine colors by change them via variables in sass files (Bootstrap 4).

```
$theme-colors: (
   primary: red,
);
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

If you use same keys for your colors, you will redefine Bootstrap. Otherwise, with new keys you create new classes.

This example set **primary color from blue to red**.

Comment: for laravel 5.7, change theme color  in _variables.scss.

Answer (score 13):

Try this method

Add a *class* to the `button` , Here *custom-btn* and write the css for that in our *stylesheet*.

```css
.btn-primary.custom-btn {
 background-color: #000;
 border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn">Custom</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Default</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the Bootstrap 4 **stable** version in your answers. Alpha is already very old.

Comment: This doesn't cover the hover and active states.

Answer (score 7):

As per bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#modifiers)

> Many of Bootstrap’s components are built with a base-modifier class
>   approach. This means the bulk of the styling is contained to a base
>   class (e.g., .btn) while style variations are confined to modifier
>   classes (e.g., .btn-danger). These modifier classes are built from the
>   $theme-colors map to make customizing the number and name of our
>   modifier classes.

So If you change theme color then it will affect all.

Maybe you should add color in [**$theme-colors**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L75) variable if you want to use that color other places as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem: I wanted to make the button match its container colors.

So I created a btn class that adapts automatically to its parent color on page load. I'm pretty happy with the result (In fact I'm even creating a little plugin). [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm56Z/7ypjaeLn/)

```js
/*
** Author: Jean-Marc Zimmer
** Licence: MIT
*/

$(function() {

  const hexDigits = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

  function hex(x) {
    return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
  }
  function hexify(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
  }
  function darken(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    return "rgb(" + parseInt(0.9 * rgb[1]) + ',' + parseInt(0.88 * rgb[2]) + ',' + parseInt(0.87 * rgb[3]) + ')';
  }

  function getParentBackground($elem) {
    var color = $elem.css("background-color");
    if (color && color !== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
      return color;
    return ($elem.is('body') ? false : getParentBackground($elem.parent()));
  }

  function getParentColor($elem) {
    var color = $elem.css("color");
    if (color && color !== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
      return color;
    return ($elem.is('body') ? false : getParentColor($elem.parent()));
  }

  $('.btn-negative, .btn-outline-negative').each(function() {
    var bgColor = hexify(getParentBackground($(this).parent()));
    var color = hexify(getParentColor($(this).parent()));
    var rgb = getParentColor($(this).parent());
    this.style.setProperty('--btn-negative-color0', bgColor);
    this.style.setProperty('--btn-negative-color1', color);
    this.style.setProperty('--btn-negative-shadow-color', color + "88");
    this.style.setProperty('--btn-negative-color2', hexify(darken(rgb)));
    this.style.setProperty('--btn-negative-color3', hexify(darken(darken(rgb))));
  });

});
```

```css
/*
** Author: Jean-Marc Zimmer
** Licence: MIT
*/

.btn-negative::before,
.btn-outline-negative::before {
  --btn-negative-color0: #fff;
  --btn-negative-color1: #000;
  --btn-negative-color2: #000;
  --btn-negative-color3: #000;
  --btn-negative-shadow-color: #0008;
}

.btn-outline-negative {
    background-color: var(--btn-negative-color0);
    border: solid 1px var(--btn-negative-color1);
    color: var(--btn-negative-color1);
}

.btn-negative,
.btn-outline-negative.active,
.btn-outline-negative:hover:not(.disabled):not([disabled]),
.btn-outline-negative:active:not(.disabled):not([disabled]) {
    background-color: var(--btn-negative-color1);
    color: var(--btn-negative-color0);
}

.btn-negative.active,
.btn-negative:hover:not(.disabled):not([disabled]),
.btn-negative:active:not(.disabled):not([disabled]) {
    background-color: var(--btn-negative-color2);
    color: var(--btn-negative-color1);
}

.btn-negative.active:hover,
.btn-negative:hover:active:not(.disabled):not([disabled]) {
    background-color: var(--btn-negative-color3);
    color: var(--btn-negative-color1);
}

.btn-negative:focus,
.btn-outline-negative:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem var(--btn-negative-shadow-color);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>Some text...</p>
        <button class="btn btn-success">btn-success</button>
        <button class="btn btn-negative">btn-negative</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">btn-outline-success</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-negative">btn-outline-negative</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Due to the CSS call order in the snippet, the style doesn't apply correctly.

Any idea to make it better is welcomed !

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom css sheet and override the button style or add the button a new class and override some of the properties.

```
<button class="btn-primary">Button</button>

.btn-primary{
    background-color:black;
}

<button class="btn-primary custom-btn-class">Button</button>

.custom-btn-class{
     background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: I am looking for bootstrap 4 solutions

Comment: @Jocket So how is this not a BS 4 solution?

Answer (score -2):

```
<a  class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">Find out more</a>



.featured  .btn-secondary {
     font-weight: bold;
     background-color: blue;
}
```

**Just edit in css it works for me**