# Different background images for different Jinja2 templates

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have multiple templates in Jinja2 that extend my layout. They require different backgrounds. I've followed the instructions in the docs located here 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/templateinheritance/#child-template,
but can't seem to get them to work. Thoughts on what is going wrong?

Here's the relevant section of layout.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        <title>Verbatim: Book Reviews & Recommendations</title>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Fontawesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+English+SC" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Additional CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
```

And here's the template in which I'm trying to insert a different background image:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(yellowed-paper-texture.jpg);
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container h-100 my-5 form">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form">
           etc ....
```

EDIT:
My CSS file doesn't appear to contain anything exciting that would abridge the inheritance process.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  div.ratings {
    font-size: 13px; } 
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #siteName {
    font-size: 26px; }

  #siteSubTitle {
    font-size: 20px; }

  #siteTagLine {
    font-size: 14px; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  #siteName {
    font-size: 26px; }

  #siteSubTitle {
    font-size: 20px; }

  #siteTagLine {
    font-size: 14px; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #siteName {
    font-size: 36px; }

  #siteSubTitle {
    font-size: 30px; }

  #siteTagLine {
    font-size: 24px; } }
#siteName, #siteSubTitle, #siteTagLine {
  font-family: "IM Fell English SC", serif; }

.blank_row {
  height: 10px !important;
  /* overwrites any other rules */
  background-color: #FFFFFF; }

a.nav-link {
  color: #E8E8EE !important; }

a.nav-link:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFD700; }

.navbar.navbar-expand-md {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #FFFFFF; }

div.container.siteTitle {
  background-image: url(yellowed-paper-texture.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }

.banner {
  background-image: url(yellowed-paper-texture.jpg);
  height: 20vh; }

.black-border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black; }

#loginPrompt {
  font-family: "IM Fell English SC", serif; }

/*change btn color by adding custom-btn class*/
/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184471*/
.btn-primary.custom-btn {
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: #000; }
```

Comment: Your problem might be css, what's the content of your `styles.css` file?

Comment: @LuisOrduz Hi Luis, checked my CSS, couldn't find anything that stoof out as problematic. The text is above, if you'd like to look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

```
body {
    background-image: url(yellowed-paper-texture.jpg);
}
```

The url link needed to be `url('/static/yellowed-paper-texture.jpg')`.