# Bootstrap 4 - Modify disabled button styling via SASS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I am using `bootstrap4` and trying to change some button colors using `SASS`. In my custom `SCSS` file I have the following...

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$theme-colors: (
    "primary": red
);
```

When compiled, this is working correctly. Now I want to modify the disabled state of primary buttons in the same way.

I am struggling to find any examples. Can anyone point me to one?

Answer (score 1):

Available varibles for disabled buttons :

This for changing the background opacity of a disabled button

```
`$btn-disabled-opacity` *Default value:* 0.65
```

This for changing disabled link button text color (`<a class="btn btn-primary disabled"> Disabled link  </a>`)

```
`$btn-link-disabled-color` *Default value* $gray-600
```

If you want to create your own Bootstrap theme you can take a look at this [online builder](https://bootstrap.build/) he will help you with variables names and values

Comment: I wanted to change the background color rather than just the opacity

Comment: by default the disabled button will inherit the background color of the button (primary, danger, info, ..) if you want custom color you can add a color to the `$theme-colors` map and use it for disabled button

Answer (score 1):

The `button-variant` @mixin is used to build the buttons, and by default `.disabled` is a variation of the background color. The mixin doesn't have a parameter for the disabled color.

Therefore, you'd have to explicitly set the state using a selector like `.btn-primary.disabled` and recompile using the `button-variant` @mixin. For example, here is changing disabled state to grey background with black border...

```
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": red
);

@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

.btn-primary.disabled {
    @include button-variant(grey, black);
}

@import "bootstrap";
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/pi3OthqQos

---

Related question: [how to change bootstrap version 4 button color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184471/how-to-change-bootstrap-version-4-button-color)