# Bootstrap: setting custom colors

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-variables

I am using `bootstrap 4.0.0` in a project. I know that bootstrap defines variables such as `--primary` to define the color of buttons (in this case `.btn-primary`). Instead, I would like to have my custom color.
However, I didn't manage to set another "primary" color, even inserting the following snippet of code in the `HTML` files before or after the `<link>` tag for the `bootstrap.css`.

```
<style>
  :root {
     --primary: #009c68;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite bootstrap styles by adding "!important;"
For example in your html you might have something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

You can change the color like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: #009c68!important;">Primary</button>
```

In CSS, the !important means that “this is important”, ignore all the subsequent rules, and apply !important rule. For more information you can go [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/).

If this answer does not work with your given situation, I would suggest looking into Bootstrap Theming. Documentation explaining how to customize Bootstrap 4 and modify existing colors can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/).

Comment: I created a class with that color, that I add to the buttons btn-primary...

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap is originally written in SCSS and thus when it is compiled to CSS it actually does uses the color code and not the var(--primary) in the CSS,

### The code in bootstrap css file is (THE SOURCE IS GIT REPO OF BOOTSTRAP) :

```
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  border-color: #0d6efd;
}
```

### And Not

```
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  border-color: var(--primary);
}
```

If you want to customize this option you will have to download the files rather than the CDN and edit the SCSS and compile it.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the `:root` [CSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/#css-variables) like `--primary` as **"read-only"**. They can be referenced like..

`background-color: var(--primary)`

But, trying to change the original value of `--primary` will do nothing:

```
:root {
     --primary: #009c68;
}
```

This has no effect because Bootstrap's CSS is compiled from SASS variables.

To change/override the color of `btn-primary` you should see these questions:
[How to change the bootstrap primary color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792005/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-primary-color/50253707#50253707)
[How to change btn color in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261287/how-to-change-btn-color-in-bootstrap/50973207#50973207)