# How can I set Bootstrap 5's CSS variables using :root?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, css-variables

I have a [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) application that consumes a bunch of web components and all of the components use Bootstrap 5. I need to customize the theme on the fly inside of the parent that consumes all of these web components. My basic structure is like this:

```
<div>
  <div>I'm the wrapper around many web components</div>
  <abc-comp />
  <xyz-comp />
</div>
```

I would like to be able to pierce the shadow DOM of `abc-comp` and `xyz-comp` by setting Bootstrap's variables in the consumer.

I see that Bootstrap 5 has [CSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/css-variables/) so I am trying to override those variables by setting them in my own CSS `:root` styling like this:

```css
:root {
  --bs-primary: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary">
  Why is my color not tomato?
</button>
```

How can I set Bootstrap's CSS variables in my own stylesheets where I consume many web components that all have bootstrap as a dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Bootstrap you are using apparently doesn't support customization via custom variables. At least for customization of button colors. Try using v. 5.2 which is beta for now:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<style>
.btn-primary {
  --bs-btn-bg: tomato;
  --bs-btn-border-color: tomato;
}
</style>

<button class="btn btn-primary">
 I like tomato!
</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set primary color globally on root this way? `:root { --bs-primary: #274E13 }` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps... But you can edit the sass file inside the bootstrap folder that it's on your node_module folder.

They have there lots of variables and you can add your styles the standard.

Your colors, for example.

Comment: Thanks, however, I need to be able to _override_ the defaults and change them on the fly. I still want the default colors to stay.

Comment: In this case, I would use it with the CDN, and your css would have priority.

Comment: This post might help as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles

Comment: how can I override it with the fiddle I provided in the question? That is using a CDN and I cannot override the bootstrap variables

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a duplicate of [Bootstrap: setting custom colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567417/bootstrap-setting-custom-colors/59578099#59578099)

The :root CSS variables are read-only and can't be changed at "runtime". The only way to do what you want is to re-define the CSS variable using SASS

Comment: Based on reading [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50253707/4826740) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50973207/4826740) it seems like the way that this could be done and still pierce the shadow DOM would be to create _my own_ theme variables outside of the shadow DOM and then before I import bootstrap but after I've imported the necessary bootstrap files like `variables` and `functions`  I could do something like `$theme-colors: (primary: --theme-primary;);` where `--theme-primary` is set in my own `:root` right?