# CSS add custom background color to checkbox

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I do want to style a checkbox like this

[image]

White color border, White color tick mark, and dark blue (#283550) for the background.

I tried this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .watchlist {
            outline: 2px solid white;
            background-color: #283550;
        }
        .wrapper {
            padding: 3rem;
            background-color: #283550;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <input type="checkbox" class="watchlist">
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

adding the white border was successful. But still, I can see a grey color border inside and also unable to fill the background with dark blue color.

How do I achieve this to work in any modern web browser?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570835/4826740) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the `appearance` property of checkbox a will result in a completely customized appearance.

Also use the `:before` & `:after` pseudo to style the checkbox tick element on `:checked` property.

Note: Use vendor prefix for wider browser support. (Firefox, Safari, etc.)

```css
body {
  background: #283550;
}


/* custom checkbox */

.custom-checkbox {
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  appearance: none;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #283550;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.custom-checkbox:checked {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.custom-checkbox:checked:before,
.custom-checkbox:checked:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}

.custom-checkbox:checked:before {
  width: 6px;
  top: 11px;
  left: 3px;
  transform: rotate(44deg);
}

.custom-checkbox:checked:after {
  width: 12px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

.custom-checkbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Bootstrap 5 [Checkbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/), and update your HTML code with the following code

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input watchlist" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
      Checked checkbox
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and your CSS with following code

```
.watchlist {
  outline: 2px solid white;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #283550;
  color: white;
}
.form-check-input:checked{
  background-color: #283550;
  border-color: #283550;
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

The checkbox you're using is the default Firefox design. It'll look different on other browsers so I'd suggest you stick to [Bootstrap buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/).

To change the color of the bootstrap button, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261287/how-to-change-btn-color-in-bootstrap).