# Is there a way to work around the color restrictions in bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, colors

I just started learning bootstrap and I am currently following a crash course video, and the developer did this

and I checked and there are like a finite set of colors like danger, warning, primary, and so on. I was wondering if I could use tomato red instead of dark.

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261287/how-to-change-btn-color-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change btn color in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261287/how-to-change-btn-color-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular css to add custom colors, for example, in your html, you can create your own class:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-tomato-red">My button</button>`

Then in your css apply your custom styles to that class:

```
.btn-tomato-red {
    background-color: #ff6347;
    color: #ffffff
}
```