# how do i change bootstrap nav-bar color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to change my bootstrap nav bar color. I used TWBSColor to make a custom color. This is what i want:

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffd2d2;
  border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
  }
}
```

And this is what it is:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

.img-portfolio {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.img-hover:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Home Page Carousel */

header.carousel {
    height: 50%;
}

header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* 404 Page Styles */

.error-404 {
    font-size: 100px;
}

/* Pricing Page Styles */

.price {
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.price sup {
    top: -20px;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.period {
    display: block;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Footer Styles */

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}

/* Responsive Styles */

@media(max-width:991px) {
    .customer-img,
    .img-related {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    .img-portfolio {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    header.carousel .carousel {
        height: 70%;
    }
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffd2d2;
  border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
  }
}
```

But i dont know how to add it ;( please help...

Comment: You mean you don't know to override BootstrapCSS core file with your own styles? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template

Comment: it's not good idea to overwrite `bootstrap.css ` styles. create your own styles in `styles.css`, for example:  `.navbar-custom {  background-color: #ffd2d2; border-color: #000000;}`   etc.

Comment: i really don't know what i need to do... Can somebody do it for me because i'm trying for hours now...

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. It looks like you already added it to what you want. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: the bar color is not showing, i tried everything but the color still is grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is just customize the navbar background color, the easiest way is just open the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and change these two variables to suit your taste. The first one is for `default` and second is for `inverse` navbar variety.

```
@navbar-default-bg
@navbar-inverse-bg
```

Of course, whenever you upgrade to the next version of bootstrap, you have to remember this and make the proper variable change before downloading.

The second usual option is to install `jekyll`, `node`, `grunt` and other bootstrap dependencies and build `bootstrap` yourself by changing `variables.less`, but this method is an overkill if all you need is to customize background color. However, details about this second way is also provided in the Bootstrap Customizer page.