# How to set custom button text color in Bootstrap 4 and Sass?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

I would like to create a new button style in Bootstrap 4 with a white (#fff) text color. Mixin `button-variant` automatically sets the text color based on the background color. How can I use this mixin and set the color at the same time, without modifying `_buttons.scss`?

**custom.scss**

```
.my_button {
  @include button-variant(HOW TO SET TEXT COLOR TO WHITE?);
}
```

**_buttons.scss**

```
@mixin button-variant($background, $border, $hover-background: darken($background, 7.5%), $hover-border: darken($border, 10%), $active-background: darken($background, 10%), $active-border: darken($border, 12.5%)) {
  color: color-yiq($background);
  @include gradient-bg($background);
  border-color: $border;
  @include box-shadow($btn-box-shadow);

  @include hover {
    color: color-yiq($hover-background);
    @include gradient-bg($hover-background);
    border-color: $hover-border;
  }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is similar to: [How to create new set of color styles in Bootstrap 4 with sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382588/how-to-create-new-set-of-color-styles-in-bootstrap-4-with-sass/39390224)

You need to use @include for the custom button, set the `color:`, and pass in the appropriate mixin params...

```
.btn-custom {
    @include button-variant(pink, red, red, #444, #333, red);
    color: #fff;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/EHwnjvUXac

---

Related: [Extending Bootstrap 4 and SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755065/extending-bootstrap-4-and-sass/49755426#49755426)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I forgot to mention I am using `<a>` instead of `<button>`. Looks like this doesn't work with `<a>`. Any idea how to solve this without using `<button>`?

Comment: Thank you! It works. I tried `color: #fff;` before, but it looks like I forgot to disable cache in my browser :)