# Customizing Bootstrap 4 css

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am following this link:
[Docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/)

Specifically:
**Customize Bootstrap 4 with our built-in custom variables file and easily toggle global CSS preferences with new $enable-* Sass variables. Override a variable’s value and recompile with the included Gruntfile as needed.**

I have never used Gruntfile before. Can I use other tools to compile scss into css? Also, what the outcome of such compilation is going to be? A _custom.css that must be placed in the same folder where original bootstrap.css is?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use Gulp as an alternative to Grunt, but be aware that Bootstrap4 is still in the alpha stage. It would be recommended to use Bootstrap 3 until the final build is released.

Comment: I agree with you, but I still need to learn how to do it.

Comment: Here is a [Bootstrap SASS to CSS customizer tool](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/bootstrap-4-customizer) that lets you set the variables.

Comment: Oh, this is just great! Thanks

Comment: @Mark - will you please accept an answer for this question so others know it's resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is not an "official" Bootstrap 4 customizer like [there was in 3.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/), there are several tools that can do this. These all convert from SASS to CSS, and some provide a UI if you're not familiar with SASS.

[Themestr.app Customizer](https://themestr.app/customize)

[Bootply Customizer](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/bootstrap-4-customizer)

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50410667/171456) for details on how to customize with CSS overrides or SASS.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need to know too much about Grunt. Bootstrap 4 provides doc on how to setup build tools which can be found at,

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup

> Run grunt (or a specific set of Grunt tasks) to rebuild distributed CSS and JavaScript files, as well as our docs assets.

My suggestion is to clone the Bootstrap Beta 4 from Github change the variable and rebuild using the reconfigure gruntfile.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#running-documentation-locally

Comment: In the Tooling setup it says something about Ruby. I am having a problem adding a SASS gem to it. Should I make it definitely work?

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Also it says "To use our Gruntfile and run our documentation locally, ..." Does that include bootstrap.css that I use in my app?

Comment: When I am adding SASS gem it's timed out.

Comment: Yes, it should include the bootstrap css files

Comment: I can also compile scss files using Scout-App application. Is it the same?