# Unable to override $theme-color in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

It's bootstrap 4.0 with `SASS`

My `style.scss` file contains the following code:

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

@import "colors";
@import "main";
```

and `_colors.scss` file contains the following code:

```
$bg-white : white;

$theme-colors: (
        primary: #333333
)
```

You can see that I am just trying to override the `$theme-color('primary')` but the problem is this that it does nothing.

And If I shift `@import "colors"` in the start of the file `style.scss` It gives me following error:

> error ../bootstrap/scss/_forms.scss (Line 284: $color: null is not a
>   color for `rgba')

Actually, the `style.scss` file compiles to `style.css` file and that one is linked file.

**Question:** How I can override the `$theme-color` in `bootstrap-4` when using `SASS`?

Any help will be appreciated, and Thanks in advance

Cheers.

Comment: good question , same problem also may be named like: `Argument $color of darken($color, $amount) must be a color`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update 2021 for Bootstrap 5**

Per the [guidance in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#importing)...

> "Variable overrides must come after our functions are imported, but
> ***before*** the rest of the imports."

Therefore, overriding the theme-colors in Bootstrap 5 works the same way as 4.x. In order to override the theme-colors, simply change appropriate theme color variable before importing bootstrap.scss

```
/* custom.scss */
/* change theme colors */
$primary: #362ec4;
$secondary: #8f5325;
$success: #3e8d63;
$info: #7854e4;
$warning: #b8c924;
$danger: #d62518;
/* end custom.scss */

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

---

**Update 2018 for Bootstrap 4.1**

To change the **primary**, or any of the **theme colors** in Bootstrap 4 SASS, set the appropriate variables *before* importing `bootstrap.scss`. This allows your custom scss to override the default value, and will then be set in all the `theme-colors` loops (btn-primary, bg-primary, text-primary, etc..)...

```
/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$theme-colors: (
  primary: #333333;
);

/* finally, import Bootstrap */
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/lobGxGgfZE

---

[Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50410667/171456)

Comment: I have try this with latest v4.1.2. but, I get error this `Error: File to import not found or unreadable: utilities/screenreaders.` how can i resolved? Thanks.

Comment: @HDP Instead of importing functions and variables, do that `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot";`

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski - that works too but it also adds mixins which is unnecessary for theme-colors customization.

Comment: It is bit a shame, that bootstrap does not provide a simple guideline for implementing customizations. @Zim you're right. Now I changed my method.

Comment: I believe you need to remove the semi-colon after #333333. Throws an error for me.

Comment: Starting in bootstrap 5.2, there is a _map.scss which needs to be imported after defining new variables. $theme-colors-rgb and $utilities-text are defined in this _map.scss

Comment: The docs implied that assigning the `$theme-colors` variable would override the defaults. Had to assign each color top-level.

Answer (score 12):

This got me too.  You need to import functions.scss into your scss file before variables.

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'assets/styles/variables';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Your paths may differ.

This is with Bootstrap 4 Beta 1.

Comment: This is the answer I was finding out for myself as well. Without the functions above variables, it does not compile `theme-color("primary")` correctly because there's a function called `theme-color` inside of functions.

Comment: Confirmed doesn't seem to work at the moment. In fact when I try this it still throws the error.

Answer (score 8):

None of the solutions provided work. Some are close and will update the color use on most elements, but not all elements. I have tried them all (and every other alternative I can find on StackOverflow and other websites, but those solutions only affect the elements that are specifically referencing the color property and does not update those using the theme-color function to get the color.

The expected solution (and recommended by others) is

```
/* import only the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

/* -------begin customization-------- */
$colors: (
  "" + blue: #004C9E
);

/* 80 required to bring primary and secondary colors to AAA standards */
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #004C9E
);

// /* -------end customization-------- */

/* finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes! */
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But this leaves 15 occurences of #007bff (the normal blue/primary color) throughout the generated custom.css. Examples of it occur in the pagination section, e.g.

```
.page-item.active .page-link {
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #007bff;
}
```

By setting both the $colors and the $theme-colors custom properties after the import of the functions.scss, and placing the statement to import the variables.scss AFTER these changes appears to set the new colors throughout. I presume that by setting these variables specifically, the bootstrap variables cannot override them.

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

/* -------begin customization-------- */
$colors: (
  "" + blue: #004C9E
);

/* 80 required to bring primary color to AAA standards */
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #004C9E
);

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

/* put other customization in here */

// /* -------end customization-------- */

/* finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes! */
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

The may not seem right, but it does appear to work. I'm not a SASS expert, so maybe someone else could explain this better. I hope this helps anyone who may still be struggling to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you have installed `Bootstrap 4 beta` using `npm` and you wish to customize the Bootstrap SCSS without modifying the source in `node_modules`.

The way I do it is by overriding the Bootstrap variables contained in `variables.scss`:

**app-styles.scss**

```css
// Custom SCSS variables I wish to override (see below)
@import 'assets/styles/variables';

// Bootstrap 4 from node_modules
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

**variables.scss**

```css
$theme-colors: (
    primary: $trump-hair,
    secondary: $gandalf-hat,
    success: $my-favorite-color,
    info: #FBC02D,
    warning: #FF5722,
    danger: $color-of-melena,
    light: #1B5E20,
    dark: $bile-green
);
```

The way to override bootstrap theme colors is actually due to be changed in the upcoming beta 2. The current requirement is that you have to include the entire `theme-colors` Sass map when overriding. In the current beta, failure to include the entire Sass map will result in:

> Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color

Please see this Github [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23112) and this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaJeVd) for more information, and an example of how you will be able to override theme colors in beta 2.

Comment: What's the correct way of getting those values? I see theme-colors('blue') in the bootstrap scss files, but I'm getting errors..

Comment: Its just a Sass Map: map-get($theme-colors, primary)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was `maps`.
In **Bootstrap 5.3**, if you have imported maps, then the overridden color will not work.

Remove this.

```
@import '../lib/bootstrap/scss/maps';
```

If you require `maps` for [Bootstrap Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/api/) API, you need to create a new .scss file and include utilities changes.