# Variable overrides do not fully override

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I have set up my project via npm install to take advantage of sass overrides. Everything looks to be working, but when I adjust the `$theme-colors`, it only works on part of the page?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I tried:

```
$theme-colors: ("primary": #FF9671)

// Bootstrap Sass Files
@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

and

```
$primary: #FF9671
$theme-colors: ("primary": #FF9671)
$link: $primary

// Bootstrap Sass Files
@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

Also as a side note, Bootstrap says that I only need to import:

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/functions"
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables"
@import "../bootstrap/scss/mixins"
```

However, this results in nothing happing at all, hence I'm having to import the whole `bootstrap.scss` file to see any results. Which seems like total overkill?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Consider the way some of the Bootstrap variables are set in the `variables.scss`...

```
$link-color: theme-color("primary") !default;
$component-active-bg: theme-color("primary") !default;
```

This is different than the way other `theme-color()` dependent variables (bg-, alert-, text-, etc...) are set (by iterating the theme-colors map). Therefore, instead of importing "functions" and "variables" first, just override the `$primary` theme-color like this...

```
$theme-colors: ();
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #FF9671
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

Demo 1: https://www.codeply.com/go/gX4Ye5iZgp

***Or,*** you can simply override $primary like this...

```
$primary: #FF9671;
@import "bootstrap";
```

Demo 2: https://www.codeply.com/go/5tdlvOVTv3

---

Related: [Unable to override $theme-color in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200316/unable-to-override-theme-color-in-bootstrap-4/51426049#51426049)

Answer (score 0):

After much tuting and head scratching, I finally noticed that I was pulling in files in the wrong order.

*File structure*

```
css/  
|– bootstrap/  
|– custom/  
   _all.sass  
   _variables.sass  
|– main.sass
```

*Original main.sass*

```
@charset "utf-8"

@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
@import "custom/all"
```

The custom was at the bottom, when it should be above it. As such:

*main.sass*

```
@charset "utf-8"

@import "custom/all"
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

I thought the order only mattered in my `variables` file, which looked like this:

```
$theme-colors: ("primary": #FF9671)

// Bootstrap Sass Files
@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

This also made me realise I do not need to `@import` bootstrap within my `variables` file. As I am importing in my `main.sass`. Which now looks like this:

*main.sass*

```
@charset "utf-8"

@import "custom/all"
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

and hence my variables file is simply as such:

*variables.sass*

```
$primary: #845EC2
```