# Overriding Bootstrap 5 colors doesn't change btn color classes

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/ijash/customizing-bootstrap-5-color-theme-in-create-react-app-48d7), I've managed to override Bootstrap 5 default colors in my React application created with `create-react-app`. Inside my `/src/scss/custom.scss` I can call any of my new defined variables and use it at will, and even new created classes inside `custom.scss` are working just fine. Nevertheless, the default Bootstrap classes that use colors (as `btn-primary`, `bg-secondary` or `text-white`) doesn't change at all. When I use `btn-primary`, for example, the button color is the same old blue color that is the default Bootstrap primary color.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you @import Bootstrap ***after*** the `custom.scss`. This will let your changes override the theme color **!default**s in Bootstrap `variables.scss` (referenced in bootstrap.scss).

```
/* custom.scss */
$primary: #362ec4;
$secondary: #8f5325;
$success: #3e8d63;
$info: #7854e4;
$warning: #b8c924;
$danger: #d62518;
$light: #f8f9fa;
$dark: #343a40;
/* end custom.scss */

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

[React on Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/1Q8JQZmHVz)

Also, note the article is unnecessarily re-building the theme-colors map which isn't necessary unless you're adding a new theme color variant ie; $accent.

Also see: [Unable to override $theme-color in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200316/unable-to-override-theme-color-in-bootstrap/51426049#51426049)

Comment: I'm importing `custom.scss` in my `index.js` file (the file with `ReactDOM.render()` method, the same place where I import the `bootstrap.min.css`. Should I do any changes in the `package.json` scripts in order to recompile bootstrap everytime I run `npm start` to start the development server?

Comment: I don't think you should be importing bootstrap.min.css at all. It will negate any changes in custom.scss.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer because it get the root of the problem: I indeed was importing bootstrap.min.css AFTER importing custom.scss, so this was overiding all changes I'd made in Bootstrap.