# Make a custom grid structure for bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all my english not perfect, sorry about that.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and trying to custom grid, but I can't. I use a code structure like that but I don't know how to do inside ".container" > ".col-md-6" full width.

I also add an image, thinking that I can't explain my problem. > [IMAGE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP2wP.jpg)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Some content</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">Empty</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Carousel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template)

Comment: did u load bootstrap correctly?

Comment: @NitinBisht Yes I did.

Comment: Can you show your that code. let me check once.