# css active wont work only always default bootstrap active class will

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried everything to change the active background in CSS but the it only uses the default btn-primary boostrap active background.

```
 <button id="home" type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" 
href="#home">Home</button>

.btn:active, .btn:hover, .btn:target{
   background-color: rb(0, 0, 0, .7);

}
```

Comment: `.btn:active` is not the same as `.btn.active` - the former is a pseudo-class (for the [active state of an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)), whereas the latter is just a class. Which are you trying to target?

Answer (score 1):

That's because of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

The Bootstrap selector is `.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active`, so to override it use the same, or a more specific selector...

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/NrPynXwP01

**There's no reason to use `!important`**, and it's [not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css).

---

Also see:
[Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template)

Answer (score 0):

Enforce your CSS selector to overcome the Bootstrap CSS selector. The easiest way to do it is to append `!important`:

```
.btn:active, .btn:hover, .btn:target {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7) !important;
}
```

You can read more about CSS Specificity (how browsers decide which of intersecting CSS rules to apply) [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: It's really bad habit tot use `!important`in CSS.

Comment: @AlexanderN.Morgunov I agree. I don't say it's the best option. I say it's the simplest one.