# Custom CSS Bootstrap Is Not Applied

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My custom CSS file is not overriding the bootstrap.min.css unless I use `!important` tag in the class

This will change the color of my background header

```
.bg-grey{
    background-color:#333 !important;
}
```

While this won't

```
.bg-grey{
    background-color:#333;
}
```

Any idea why this is happening because I've put the external sheet right in the same directory?

Comment: You should read up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Also, be sure to load your CSS after Bootstrap

Comment: You have to learn about CSS specificity. There is probably a more specific selector overriding your style.

Comment: Use the browser inspector to check the object class. Maybe  is not only .bg-grey, probably as suggested by others you must verify the specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens because your bootstrap.min.css is being parsed after your custom file.
What order are you including the css files in your head?
You should be sure that your custom file is being included *after* your bootstrap file.

Comment: sure, my custom css is placed below the bootstrap css in the head tag.

Comment: I'm just trying to troubleshoot here.
If you inspect the element, is there a more specific selector that is overriding it?
example:
".header .inner .bg-grey"
it could be that you need to be more specific with your selector in order to override the bootstrap selector perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Using `!important` is considered to be acceptable for utility/helper classes, and Bootstrap's authors have [chosen to use `!important`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24836) on *all* of the Bootstrap 4 [Utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/).

The [background color utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color) (`bg-*`) use `!important`, so you must use `!important` for any custom color overrides to take precedence.

However, `bg-grey` isn't a color that's included in Bootstrap 4. If you're defining a custom color, make sure the overrides follow any previous CSS definition of bg-grey.

Comment: Here's another case. So here's the initial code from the bootstrap template i downloaded it and i cann't simply change the color, unless i put the !important tag.                                                                                                                                      #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: .9rem;
    padding: .75rem 0;
}

Comment: That's a different question. You should [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template/50410667#50410667) and **learn about CSS specificity**.