# Bootstrap 4 Add to map - Adding additional theme-color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

How can add custom new theme color without touching bootstrap variable.scss?

Please note I can update the existing color successfully, but I couldn't add new theme color in that same way

**File structure**

```
@import 'custom_variables';
@import './bootstrap/bootstrap'; 
@import './pages/home';
```

**custome_variables.scss**

```
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #2c67f4, // successfully edited existing color  
    "danger": #ff4136,
    "custom" : "red" // not working when adding new color theme
);
```

**Tried with code but no luck**

```
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "custom":  "red",
  ),
  $theme-colors
);
```

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#add-to-map)

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the variables first...

```
/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #2c67f4,
    "danger": #ff4136,
    "custom" : red
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/mdlTSDbmUG

Also see: [Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template)

Answer (score 1):

```css
$theme-colors: (
  "custom-color": #900
);
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-custom-color">Sign up free</button>
```

Try this! It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with bootstrap changes the imports order is crucial. I went one step further and used updated mapping to create summary mapping for all colors, but for no reason (like i thought) my new colors were in theme-colors, they were working fine, but all-colors mapping had just my local update, so what i had to do was to import once again the updated variable from bootstrap. Here's my assets structure:

_variables.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions"; // import only required things
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";              

$theme-colors: (                                   
    'error': $danger,                              
    'warn': $warning,                              
);                                               

// reimport to use updated mapping, not only local one                                          
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";           

$all-colors: () !default;                          
$all-colors: map-merge($all-colors, $theme-colors);
$all-colors: map-merge($all-colors, $colors);      
$all-colors: map-merge($all-colors, $grays);
```

style.scss

```
@import 'variables';                  
@import 'exports';                    
@import 'functions';                  
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'; 
@import 'custom';
```