# How to styling textarea like input field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, textarea

I have a problem with styling a textarea, i use bootstrap 4 css

i was trying to styling by my self but if i using a padding or margin it's make the textarea height to big

```css
.comment-box {
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control comment-box" rows="1"></textarea>
```

i want this textarea look like input field with button in inside just like this image

[textarea input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa7W7.jpg)

Comment: You style it as you would style an `input`... just add a `resize: none` to remove the option to the user rezise the box. But, why to use a textarea to look like an input instead of using a real input?

Comment: why I use textarea, because for the comments column that can accommodate a lot of text

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8672691/12032180)
is the complete explanation about overriding bootstrap style. I am sure you can follow that rule and solve that issue.

Edit:
Also you don't need to implement his first and second step. You can follow only 3 and create new style that override the bootstrap style

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_contact_form.asp">here is a link to your answer

that should solve your issue, check out the css they use and play with it.

```
input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background: #4aaaa5;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```