# How to properly introduce a light/dark mode in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I use [Bootstrap 4.5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/) and use `bg-dark` in my HTML template. I would like to implement a "light/dark" switch.

So, Bootstrap has a `bg-light` css class, but I am not sure what the current approach how to use it. Let me clarify my confusion:

1. Am I supposed to replace all occurrences of `bg-dark` with `bg-light` once the "switch" is turned on?
2. If I want to slightly modify the colors of `bg-light` and `bg-dark`, is "Theming" the right approach? I can't find any examples to override these variables (via SASS), except of manually overwrite them in my CSS like `.bg-dark { ... }`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark. Example `test-nightfall.html` and `test-nightshade.html` has a class switch for dark/light that you can modify to change the `bg-*` class instead.

Comment: Thanks vino, I found this but didn't know if this was the right way to go for me. I was wondering if that limits me to use this specific bootstrap version since I use `v4.5` and might switch to `v5` soon

Comment: I'd +1000 vino's work here if that was an option. By far, the most comprehensive treatment on the subject, and the 'option 4' stuff is, quite frankly, awesome.

Comment: For Bootstrap 5 a comprehensive guide is here: https://github.com/vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark-5

Comment: Bootstrap now supports a dark theme!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5.3.0-alpha (update 2023)**

Bootstrap has introduced a dark mode, and the ability to create other color-modes. However, this feature is [currently limited](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/37976) to a few variables, and it's not possible to customize the dark theme colors. For the dark mode switch, simply add the `data-bs-theme` attribute to the doc's html tag:

```
<html data-bs-theme="dark">
```

Using a little JavaScript you could create a light/dark theme switch:

[Bootstrap 5.3 Dark Mode Toggle](https://www.codeply.com/p/BmyKLq8RTV)

```
document.getElementById('btnSwitch').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if (document.documentElement.getAttribute('data-bs-theme') == 'dark') {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme','light')
    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme','dark')
    }
})
```

---

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Although there is still no definitive support for light/dark mode in Bootstrap 5, SASS can be used to create a [dark theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667437/create-new-color-scheme-for-dark-light-mode-in-bootstrap-sass/68670276#68670276)

---

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

Here are some answers to your question on Bootstrap light or dark mode:

> "Am I supposed to replace all occurrences of bg-dark with bg-light
> once the "switch" is turned on?"

Yes, but you'd probably also want to switch all `-light` and `-dark` classes such as `text-dark`, `navbar-dark`, `btn-dark`, etc..

> If I want to slightly modify the colors of bg-light and bg-dark.. I
> can't find any examples to override these variables (via SASS), except
> of manually overwrite them in my CSS like .bg-dark...

These are derived from `$light` and `$dark` SASS variables so you can change them like this...

```
$light: #dddddd;
$dark: #011100;

@import "bootstrap";
```

**Demo** [Bootstrap Light Dark Mode Switch](https://codeply.com/p/bV4XYd7H9h)

Also see: 
[Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template/50410667#50410667) 
[How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142)
[Create new color scheme for dark-light mode in bootstrap sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667437/create-new-color-scheme-for-dark-light-mode-in-bootstrap-sass/68670276#68670276)

Comment: Hopping for official support in 5.3.0: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/35857

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the CSS classes that automatically correspond to the selected color mode are `bg-body`, `bg-body-secondary` and `bg-body-tertiary`.

Answer (score 24):

Update: Bootstrap 5.3 is in alpha and is starting to support Dark Mode. There are major bugs as of my last testing (for example in color interpolation), but, unless you need Dark Mode support this minute, it's probably better to either wait for Bootstrap 5.3 to get to production release, or, even better, go help it get there.

Bootstrap 4 and 5.2 do not support Dark Mode.

If you must have Dark Mode support while you wait on Bootstrap, you can get a long way by just setting your text and bg color to flip:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

Then test and tweak this; I suggest doing so in a special SASS file you plan to throw away when Bootstrap is ready.

Old Answer:

Dark Mode is a confusing name in this context because Bootstrap does support a color, `$dark: $gray-900`, and, it does support several dark-tinted classes, like `.bg-dark`. But none of these are actual Dark Mode, which is OS-driven, passed-to-browser, website rendering switching based on:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
```

Worse, things like `bg-dark` imply you would switch to Dark Mode by going around swapping class names out, probably via Javascript. That's a lot of CPU usage to perform a browser built-in, all because the Bootstrap authors ignored an important feature of the Web. Don't do this!

[All of this is detailed in a much longer way here.](https://vinorodrigues.github.io/bootstrap-dark/readme.html)

That will leave you with a lot of options, but in short for Bootstrap 4 and 5 the best, simplest, least-effort way to handle proper `prefers-color-scheme: dark` is to introduce an indirection into Bootstrap colors by reassigning the Bootstrap color SASS variables you're using to color CSS variables, in your `_variables.scss`. [CSS Variables have been supported for years](https://caniuse.com/css-variables), are perfect for Dark Mode, and largely overlooked. For example:

```
:root {
    --body-bg: #fff;
    --body-color: #000;
}

$white: var(--body-bg);
$black: var(--body-color);
$body-color: var(--body-color);
```

So far all you've done is create indirection - $white still renders as #fff just like in the default Bootstrap. But now you can flip it when the OS flips:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    --body-bg: #000;
    --body-color: #fff;
}
```

Now when the OS gets set to Dark Mode, the browser sees it and flips that media query, and your CSS variables flip. Since you've spread those variables into the compiled Bootstrap SASS via your _variables overrides, you'll see the result in rendered Bootstrap.

I did say simplest and least-effort, but you've probably noticed this is still going to be a lot of work. Bootstrap 4 and 5 just completely missed the boat on this, so, the legwork is on you. You'll need to override every color in Bootstrap you use and introduce CSS variables for them, and you'll then need to test to find colors that aren't keyed off of any variables, and go override those with a follow-up global stylesheet.

Comment: One clarification, since this post was written: Bootstrap 5 does now support dark mode.  Support exists in the v5.3 alpha as mentioned in another answer.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/

Answer (score 21):

**Bootstrap 5.3.0**

> Bootstrap now supports color modes, or themes, as of v5.3.0. Explore our default light color mode and the new dark mode, or create your own using our styles as your template.

Starting from v5.3 (currently in alpha), **color modes** are supported! Now you can add `data-bs-theme` attributes to change the theme (light/dark) of elements. Applying this to the html element will result in the entire page matching the style. You can learn more about that on the [documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/).

But if you want to change the theme based on the user's preferences (aka `prefers-color-scheme`), you need to toggle the theme attribute using javascript.

Here's a working example:

```js
// Set theme to the user's preferred color scheme
function updateTheme() {
  const colorMode = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ?
    "dark" :
    "light";
  document.querySelector("html").setAttribute("data-bs-theme", colorMode);
}

// Set theme on load
updateTheme()

// Update theme when the preferred scheme changes
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', updateTheme)
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="p-3">
    <h1>Dark Mode for Bootstrap</h1>
    <p>from Bootstrap v5.3.0, dark color modes are supported.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I like this method. I tried it and was not able to be the paragraphs to switch colors. Have you had similar experiences? My [question is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75586525/5091720)

Answer (score 2):

```css
/* Enable darkmode in a Bootstrap Page */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
        background-color: var(--bs-dark);
        color: var(--bs-light);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is far from a solution, but it does show the start of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming

> "Customize Bootstrap 4 with our new built-in Sass variables for global
> style preferences for easy theming and component changes."

Once you want apply the changes by Sass this looks like be the right path

And by their documentation the variables for change this is on "scss/_variables.scss" file

Here is another topic with some additional info how to achieve this:
[Customizing Bootstrap CSS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template/50410667#50410667)

Comment: This isn't about browser dark mode

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap now supports color modes, starting with dark mode.
On version 5.3.0 you can implement your own color mode toggler and apply the different color modes as you see fit. They support a light mode (default) and now dark mode preset theme. Color modes can be toggled globally on the  element, or on specific components and elements, thanks to the data-bs-theme attribute.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/

```
data-bs-theme="light"
data-bs-theme="dark"
data-bs-theme="auto"
```