# Bootstrap 5.3.2 theme colors

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I want to know which is the best way to handle the theme colors.
I need to change the main colors for light mode and also for dark mode.

I tried with this code but dark colors doesn't work.

```
// Light mode
$primary-light: #0850d0;
$secondary-light: #6c757d;
$success-light: #008000;
$info-light: #19b5fe;
$warning-light: #f9c80e;
$danger-light: #d91e18;
$light-light: #e0e0e2;
$dark-light: #1a2035;

// Dark mode
$primary-dark: #5590f7;
$secondary-dark: #bebebe;
$success-dark: #00d46a;
$info-dark: #19b5fe;
$warning-dark: #f9c80e;
$danger-dark: #ff6347;
$light-dark: #e0e0e2;
$dark-dark: #1a2035;

// Rewrite the Bootstrap variables with your owns variables
$theme-colors: (
        "primary": $primary-light,
        "secondary": $secondary-light,
        "success": $success-light,
        "info": $info-light,
        "warning": $warning-light,
        "danger": $danger-light,
);

$theme-colors-dark: (
        "primary": $primary-dark,
        "secondary": $secondary-dark,
        "success": $success-dark,
        "info": $info-dark,
        "warning": $warning-dark,
        "danger": $danger-dark,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75399501/change-color-of-bootstrap-theme-colors-in-dark-mode?rq=2) there's no easy way to change theme colors of "dark" mode. Also, there's no `theme-colors-dark` map.

As a workaround you could use a CSS selector to merge your custom dark colors into the `theme-colors` map...

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "variables-dark";

$primary-light: #0850d0;
$secondary-light: #6c757d;
$success-light: #008000;
$info-light: #19b5fe;
$warning-light: #f9c80e;
$danger-light: #d91e18;
$light-light: #e0e0e2;
$dark-light: #1a2035;

$primary-dark: #5590f7;
$secondary-dark: #bebebe;
$success-dark: #00d46a;
$info-dark: #19b5fe;
$warning-dark: #f9c80e;
$danger-dark: #ff6347;
$light-dark: #e0e0e2;
$dark-dark: #1a2035;

$theme-colors: (
        "primary": $primary-light,
        "secondary": $secondary-light,
        "success": $success-light,
        "info": $info-light,
        "warning": $warning-light,
        "danger": $danger-light,
);

$theme-colors-dark: (
        "primary": $primary-dark,
        "secondary": $secondary-dark,
        "success": $success-dark,
        "info": $info-dark,
        "warning": $warning-dark,
        "danger": $danger-dark,
);

[data-bs-theme="dark"] {

    $theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $theme-colors-dark);
    @import "bootstrap";
    
}

@import "bootstrap";
```

[SASS demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/jWyET0ecYM)