# Django Bootstrap Toolkit CSS editing

Tags: django

I am using Django Bootstrap toolkit, and I am wondering where the CSS and JS files are stored so I can edit them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [example project](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit/blob/master/demo_project/settings.py#L153) and [templatetags](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit/blob/master/bootstrap_toolkit/templatetags/bootstrap_toolkit.py):

```
BOOTSTRAP_BASE_URL = 'http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/'
BOOTSTRAP_CSS_BASE_URL = BOOTSTRAP_BASE_URL + 'css/'
BOOTSTRAP_CSS_URL = BOOTSTRAP_CSS_BASE_URL + 'bootstrap.css'
BOOTSTRAP_JS_BASE_URL = BOOTSTRAP_BASE_URL + 'js/'
```

So you can define your own version of the files but per default `django-bootstrap-toolkit` embeds the files directly from the Github repository.

However, in most cases it is better to leave the original files alone and overwrite the necessary declarations in your own stylesheets. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8085921/630877) to see how to do this.

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate the help, and this makes perfect sense.