# Bootstrap CSS not applied to table td

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to get rid of the "border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;" for a specific table on my Bootstrap site.

Making the change using inline styling works as expected:

```
<td style="border-top:none; font-weight:bold;">
```

However, when I try to add this into the bootstrap.css file, the font-weight is applied, but the border-top is not:

```
<td class="notop">
```

CSS (have tried with '!important' as well):

```
.notop {
  border-top:none;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this would work inline, but not via CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to overwrite styling in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I was going to suggest that it was happening because of the cascading nature of style sheets, but you said you used `!important`

Just to check, your code with `!important` looked like this:

```
.notop {
  border-top:none !important;
}
```

Sometimes CSS can be really funny with how `!important` is used.
Also, is the CSS sheet external, or embedded?  Again, the order of sheets can often cause weird errors like this.

Edit: Also, if it's an external style sheet, make sure it's included *after* the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Thanks!  I did apply '!imporant' correctly, but it appears that the problem was in the order in which my stylesheets were being called in the header file.