# How to remove the class from angular-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular-bootstrap modal and trying to remove the slide down effect when it is closed.

I tried to remove 'fade' class like this, but it didn't work.

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
    .directive 'modalWindow', ()->
        restrict:'EA'
        link:(scope,elem)->
            elem.removeClass("fade")
```

How can I access or manipulate the DOM created by angular-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than remove the class, you can simply [override the css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap).  This is copied from bootstrap.css, but I have removed the transitions responsible for the slide down effect:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
}
```

Just include your css file after you include bootstrap's css.  Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/MuIR7N51Zxe6dZFKomHq?p=preview