# How do I change the font-weight of entire html doc in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried multiple ways to do this, with no success. I'm trying to set the entire webpage in 100 font weight. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When not using Twitter Bootstrap or similar frameworks that have their own CSS settings, it would be sufficient to set

```
* { font-weight: 100 }
```

naturally assuming that all the fonts used have a typeface with weight 100. The selector `*` matches all elements.

However, Twitter Bootstrap may contrain CSS rules that override the rule above, due to higher specificity (the universal selector `*` has very low specificity). You would need to analyze what these might be and how they relate to your HTML markup and CSS code. Alternatively, you can use the `!important` specifier that makes your rule win any other rules unless they use that specifier, too:

```
* { font-weight: 100 !important; }
```

Generally, `!important` should be used as the last resort only. But if you don’t use it here, there will be the risk that some future version of Bootstrap contains rules that override yours.

P.S. Setting all text in 100 weight generally makes the page unreadable. Such typefaces are normally meant to be use in large font size only, e.g. for large-size headings.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to do something like this since all your text is located in your body. However, I see you linked bootstrap. If you are using bootstrap classes, you'll have to check and make sure they don't play around with the font-weight. If they do you need to manually override them.

**CSS**

```
body, <more elements here>{
font-weight:100;
}
```

Comment: It is not sufficient, since many elements such as `h1` and `strong` have a browser style sheet setting of `font-weight: bold`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I don't believe that deserved a downvote. While we are entitled to each his own way of voting, I wouldn't downvote an answer to promote my own. Unless of course, it was completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding there's no way to do this in a single stoke. You have to explicitly override all the default bootstrap styles with your `font-weight: 100;`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
font-weight:100 !important;
```

the !important in Bootstrap is necessary as you about writing styles commonly established

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when one-liners have a small explanation for those not familiar with the technology. It might be a good idea to explain why `!important` is needed when the OP asked for 100 point font.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it also depends how you are defining the styles. If you are using style tags it's probably not possible. But, if you are linking a CSS file, it may be by the order you are including them in the head. Make sure your overriding CSS, is below the bootstrap CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site-specific.css" />
```

This is based on [How to overwrite styling in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Then something like `* { font-weight: 100 }` should work **providing that the font you are using supports that particular weight, so make sure to verify that**.

Answer (score 0):

i find the best way is to set the CSS as follows

```
body,html{font-weight:100;}
```