# How do I give a Font Awesome icon a background color?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, background-color

In the footer for this page `http://128.199.58.229/landingpage/`

I have some Font Awesome icons (social media icons).

I'm trying to give them a white background just behind the icons themselves. The white background currently sticks out. I've read some posts on using a combination of width, height and border radius to achieve this, but currently no success.

```
.lt-bus-info .fa {
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/magician11/nfz9sucn/1/

I'm looking for just the white behind the symbol: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14057353/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-03%20at%204.01.18%20pm.png

Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357356/9031516

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [stacked icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked) instead . Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lekhnath/nfz9sucn/5/), you can play with it to make it far more better. Below is full code :

HTML

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-twitter">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-gplus">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.fa-stack-1x {
    color:white;
}
.icon-facebook {
   color:#3b5998;
}

.icon-twitter {
    color:#00aced;
}

.icon-gplus{
    color:#dd4b39;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but doesnt work:  `list.list-social> li.fa.fa-facebook.box-icon{
         background: rgba(0, 59, 89, 152);

        }` can we overide as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap) ?

Comment: finally, [this](http://ksloan.net/css-color-definitions-for-font-awesome-social-icons/) worked for me, thank you for color in fiddle, for wordpress press i used `.fa-wordpress{
     color: #464646;

}`

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this approach yet:

html

```
          <div class="social-media text-right">
            <a href="" class="facebook">
              <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
```

css

```
.social-media a
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 34px;
}
    .social-media a.facebook
    {
        background: #3b5998;
    }
```

Comment: good point. When I increase the font size though, the background doesn't cover the whole icon. http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/Vewgqp

Comment: A bit of a different question, but I have added additional css as an example for sizes.  Try playing around with width, line-height and border-radius

Answer (score 1):

I Was searching for the solution but didn't found perfect one with less code so I spend little time and made this [fiddle](//jsfiddle.net/kartic/aqfysemt/) for you.

HTML

```
<div class="background">
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fb-btn"></i>
<i class="fa fa-twitter-square twt-btn"></i>
<i class="fa fa-google-plus-square gp-btn"></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fb-btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50% 8px 10px 50%;
    color: #305891;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 30px;width: 32px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.twt-btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #2ca8d2;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 30px;
}

.gp-btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #dd4b39;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.background{
    background-color:#cccccc;
    width:150px;
    height:60px;
    padding:60px 50px;
}
```

You may need to play with some border radius, line-height and margins but that's good fit and faster solution I believe.

Let me know if there's any mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really cool way to do it that has not been mentioned here and in a couple lines of code you're gtg.

```
i.fa-smile-o {
position: relative;
color: #555;
}

i.fa-smile-o:before {
    content: "\f111";
    color: #f1c40f;
}

i.fa-smile-o:after {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: "\f118";
}
```

This way you can also fill the content with meh or frown codes that can be found [here](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/), enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest will probably to give the list item a background color like so

```
li {
background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 20%, white 20%, white 93%, transparent 93% );
    background-size: 84%;
    background-position: 60% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

[See examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357356/9031516)