# How do I change the color of the Facebook Font Awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I would like to change the color of the Font Awesome Facebook icon. If I do it with `background-color`:

```css
body {
  font-size: 5em;
  background: #555
}

.fa-facebook-square {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
```

It adds white around the edges of the blue 'background' of the Facebook logo, which I don't want.

Is there a simple solution to color only the "f" in the icon so that the color around the edges stays transparent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The icon only consists of the part around the 'f', the 'f' itself and the part around the edges are transparent. Therefore you have to create a white part only under the 'f'.

It's possible with a combination of a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position). With the gradient you create a white rectangle, that you can scale and position to only lay under the 'f'.

By using a relative unit (`%`), your white background rectangle scales with the corresponding font size.

```css
body {
  font-size: 5em;
  background: #000
}

.fa-facebook-square {
  color: #3b5998;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 20%, white 20%, white 93%, transparent 93% );
  background-size: 55%;
  background-position: 70% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the basic icon default display outcomes:

[image: Font awesome social icons]

If you use:

```
background-color: white !important;
```

Then you get this:

[image: After using background color]

If you then use:

```
background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 20%, white 20%, white 93%, transparent 93% );
background-size: 84%;
background-position: 60% 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Then the result is:

[image: background image]

Experiment with the background-size to fit your icons.

Answer (score 2):

Use stacked icons.

Stack the `fab fa-facebook-f` classes with white text over the `fa fa-square` classes with your desired background.

Re: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i style="color: blue;" class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i style="color: white;" class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SVG instead which creates no such edges.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 448 448" style="enable-background:new 0 0 448 448;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    </style>
    <rect x="125.2" y="39.5" class="st0" width="274" height="408.5"/>
    <path fill="blue" d="M448,24.7v398.5c0,13.7-11.1,24.7-24.7,24.7H309.1V274.5h58.2l8.7-67.6h-67v-43.2c0-19.6,5.4-32.9,33.5-32.9h35.8V70.3
     c-6.2-0.8-27.4-2.7-52.2-2.7c-51.6,0-87,31.5-87,89.4v49.9h-58.4v67.6h58.4V448H24.7C11.1,448,0,436.9,0,423.3V24.7
     C0,11.1,11.1,0,24.7,0h398.5C436.9,0,448,11.1,448,24.7z"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: This is not using the Font Awesome icon, though. This answer may belong on another question rather than this one. Or as a comment to a CodePen.

Answer (score 0):

It should do the job, at least in Angular + SVG combination it does. SCSS code with changing color on hover for the `fab fa-behance` class icon.

```
&:hover {
    svg {
      &.fa-facebook-f {
        path {
          transition: 1s;
          fill: #3b5998;
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want the white outline, I would remove the background-color tag. Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5m1e3ay/4/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
```

HTML:

```
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
<i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.fa-ambulance {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
  font-size:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to mention that the facebook icon is placed in a container with a gray color, that's why the white background color applied to the icon creates white edges. I do want this background because otherwise the letter 'f' has a gray color.

Comment: Maybe the solution would be to make a white container for the facebook icon? I was just hoping for an elegant solution

Comment: @sir-haver I misunderstood your question. Andreas' answer appears to be what you are looking for.