# How to convert wire frames into a layout with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was given a wireframe schematic, and based on that, I created a page layout using bootrap.  It works great and looks great, but now I need to tweak the layout to match the wireframe schematic as closely as possible -- down to the pixel.  The width and height of all columns need to be tweaked.  Does anyone have recommendations on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Make your own custom css and override the bootstrap styles.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  I found the following post to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap