# Override CSS with nothing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm editing a website and the bootstrap code is getting in my way. There is a line in the bootstrap css that says:

```
.navbar .container {
    width: auto;
}
```

If I turn the width code off in my browsers Inspect Element, then the page looks as it should. How can I write this in my css file to override it? I need it to keep it's original settings, so I can't put 100% or a specific number in there. I've also tried inherited, initial and none suggestions.

I basically want it to disable the bootstrap css without having to remove it from the bootstrap code itself.

Comment: [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: The default value for width is auto.

Comment: show us your class and the html you are trying to change

Comment: The html that I'm trying to change is in the question. That's literally all there is. I don't have that call in my css at all, but I'm putting it in to try to override it. I just don't know what to set it to. Like I mentioned, if I turn off that line in the inspect element in my browser, things go back to the way they should be.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood corectly - you want to force css systems to hear your command first and next - the bootstraps.

You can archieve that in the specification tree.

I am calling specification tree the selectors, css sorts the properties overriding by the "power" of selector.

For example:

```
.class_A .class_B { prop: value1; } /* weaker than */
.class_A > .class_B { prop: value2; } /* stronger one */
```

You can add for example to .class_B class .class_C, here I dont know what will happen, but I know this is stronger than `.class_A .class_B`

```
.class_A .class_B.class_C
.class_A > .class_B.class_C /* probably even stronger */
```

Summary:

If you want to override specific elements, just add class `.over` (override) to the DOM Elements and then you can use it in css to gain enough power to force your way of style.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually asking what I can set width to so that it uses the code that's already on the page, rather than the bootstraps width: auto.