# Set bootstrap background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-type-links

And I have seen the solutions here - such as this:

```
html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
            background:red !important;
        }
```

This isn't working - I need the background for a single page in the application to be all red - I don't want it applied universally - so I need to override the bootstrap.min.css for one page - therefore I cannot specify this color when creating the bootstrap.min.css using there online generator.

Help?

Comment: Why wouldn't you then put the CSS in that single page.. either in another file or <style></style> tag?

Comment: I am but it's not working? The background stays white no matter how I do it - I assumed BS was forcing the background white using !important?

Comment: You can write a custom script `$(document).ready(function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red" });` on that specific page to change the color of background.

Comment: That feels hackish - I am trying to keep JS to a minimal - why is this not possible with CSS?

Comment: Checkout this answer. You would get insights of css Specificity http://stackoverflow.com/a/20542297/881798

Comment: body { background : red;} It's working for me. May be it cause by something else. Can you share link, where it's not working ?

Comment: Bloody hell - sorry guys it was a caching issue or something with chrome - when I closed the browser and re-opened the file it changed as expected - my bad very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the `.html` file for the particular page you want in all red, and modify the background color within the `.html` file itself by adding a `style="background-color:#FFFFFF"` to the `<body>` tag. You can change `#FFFFFF` to the shade of red as you wish.

For example say we have the code for `index.html` below:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- some code here -->
   </head>

   <body, style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
   </body>
</html>
```

---

If that does not work, bootstrap typically has wrappers within each main body tag to represent something or the other. Take a look at the following example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- some code here -->
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <!-- some more code here -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can also change it to:

```
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper", style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
         <!-- some more code here -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can also use this technique to override any of the Bootstrap CSS files temporarily for a particular page or particular component of the page and it will **NOT** be applied universally.

Comment: Thats not working - I am adding this very CSS to a <style> on a single page and it won't change the background - when I inspect with Chrome it's still white too

Comment: Testing it out on my end with a Bootstrap application sample and it works well. How about posting the style in a div? Usually there should be something like <div id="wrapper"> and then you can change it to <div id="wrapper", style="background-color: #000000>

Answer (score 0):

Is it important do to it using online HTML and CSS? If I were you, I would have used JavaScript to determine if its the specific page and then assign the background color.

```
 <script>
  var location =  window.location.href;
if(location =="file:///C:/Users/Fahad/Desktop/index.html")
{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
  </script>
```

You will have to change the url to the link of the specific page where you want to change the color.