# Bootstrap Connection

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Kind of a newb question. I'm working with Boostrap to create a mobile responsive portfolio. What do you do if you want to make a change to the default Bootstrap classes? Like if I wanted to take the padding off of the class="container"? The links are only connected to the minified version of css and js. So if I make a change to the regular version .css, there's nothing connecting the change. Do I have to change the .min.css version? Should I be able to repeat a class in my own personal css page?(I've tried unsuccessfully) Thanks, any advice would help.

Comment: You add your own css file and add the changes there, include your css file AFTER the bootstrap css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite styling in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: You can override the classes in your own CSS file (make sure you import it into your HTML *after* the original CSS files from bootstrap) - However, if you are going to make lots of modifications like that, I suggest you create your own customized version: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods that I know of:

1) Make edits to the .min.css file, or

2) Add '!Important' to the your personal css, like so:

```
.testDiv{
       font-color: white !Important
    }
```

This will overwrite any classes that have set a font-color for .testDiv

*note: using !important is not a recommended technique, but it gets the job done

Comment: I actually saw in another post an option was to use JS Minifier. Works great. http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this approach is thta if (or when?) you need to upgrade to a newer version of the framework, you need to re-do/re-apply your changes.  This is not maintainable in the long run.  Pitty is was chosen as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can override the classes in your own CSS file (make sure you import it into your HTML after the original CSS files from bootstrap).  Like,

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Custom Tweaks to theme (Add your changes to this file) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/style.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="path/to/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

However, if you are going to make lots of modifications like that, I suggest you create your own [customized version](http://getbootstrap.com/customize)