# How do I override bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-modal

The following code turns the button text a dark color when the button is selected. I assume this comes from code embedded in Bootstrap's btn class. How can I override the code to stop the text from changing color after the button is selected?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    .buttonColor{
    color:#ff0000;
}   
.buttonColor:hover{
    color:#ffff00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button  class="buttonColor btn" > Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be more ***specific*** in your override styles.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question: [How to overwrite styling in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084964/how-to-overwrite-styling-in-twitter-bootstrap), [best way to override bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css), the list goes on.

Read up on the [CSS law of specifity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Essentially, if you're more specific in your class declaration, you can override others that are targeting the same elements:

In your example:

```
button.buttonColor.btn {
    color: red;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Will override BootStrap's `button.btn` declaration.

Similarly, add pseudo selectors to override other states:

`button.buttonColor.btn:active`, `button.buttonColor.btn:hover`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "selected" you mean the **active** state of a button, this is how you achieve it:

```
.buttonColor:active {
    color: #ffff00;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap uses both the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover),[`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) and [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-classes to target specific element states:

```
/* Example of Bootstrap :active styles for buttons */
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
```

along with :

```
/* Example of Bootstrap :focus and :hover styles for buttons */
.btn.focus, .btn:focus, .btn:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So you'll just need to explicitly override them using your own style :

```
/* The more specific your selector (e.g. the more accurately it describes an  */
/* element, the more likely a style will be applied. */
.btn.buttonColor:active,
.btn.buttonColor.active,
.btn.buttonColor:hover,
.btn.buttonColor:focus {
    color: #ffff00!important;
}
```

or if you want to be more specific, you could explicitly target `<button>` elements exclusively :

```
button.btn.buttonColor:active,
button.btn.buttonColor.active,
button.btn.buttonColor:hover,
button.btn.buttonColor:focus {
    color: #ffff00!important;
}
```

Comment: There was an extra `.button` appended to the styles. I've removed it, give that a try. You can [see it using your example code here](http://jsbin.com/nuvaho/edit?html,output).