# Multiple css files or one big css file?

Tags: html, css

Which one is better and faster? why?

using only one file for styling:

```
css/style.css
```

or

using several files for styling:

```
css/header.css
css/contact.css
css/footer.css
css/tooltip.css
```

The reason Im asking it is that im developing a site for users who have very low internet speed. country uganda. So I want to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Are you sure that you didn't find your answers in these questions? (look at the "Related" section, at the right side of this page)

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files

Comment: This might be the answer you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2336332/415057

Comment: sorry guys. Didnt see that. thanks for link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a single file is faster because it requires less HTTP requests (assuming the amount of styles loaded is still the same).

So it's better to keep it in just one file.
Separating CSS should only be done if you want to keep for example IE specific classes separate.

Answer (score 3):

As per Yahoo's Performance Rules <sup>*[[source]](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)*</sup>, It is **VERY IMPORTANT** to minimize HTTP requests

From the source

> **Combined files** are a way to reduce the number of HTTP requests by combining all scripts into a single script, and similarly combining
>   all CSS into a single stylesheet. Combining files is more challenging
>   when the scripts and stylesheets vary from page to page, but making
>   this part of your release process improves response times.

It is quite uneasy to develop using combined files, so stick to developing with multiple files but you should combine the files once you are deploying the system on the web.

I really recommend using boilerplate's ant build script. You can find it [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/wiki/Build-script).

> It Combines and minifies CSS

Answer (score 2):

This is always a better solution to *bundle* or *combine* multiple CSS or JavaScript files into fewer HTTP requests. This causes the browser to request a lot fewer files and in turn reduces the time it takes to fetch them.
With a proper caching, you can gain extra bandwidth and even fewer HTTP request.

Update:
There's a new [*Bundling* feature in ASP.Net 4.5](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx) which you might be interested in.
This allows you to have css files separated at compile-time, and in runtime gain benefit of combined resources into *one* resource

Answer (score 2):

One css file is better than multiple css files because of the overhead involved by the end user's browser to make multiple requests for each file. Other things you can do yo improve the performance include:

- Enable gzip impression on your webserver e.g. on Apache so that the files are compressed before downloading
- where possible host your files geographically as close to the majority of your end users as possible
- use a CDN network for your static content such as css files
- Use CSS sprites
- Cache your content

Note that there are tools available to help you do this. See [15 ways to optimise css](http://www.queness.com/post/588/15-ways-to-optimize-css-and-reduce-css-file-size) for more information

Answer (score 1):

One resource file is always the fastest approach since you reduce the number of HTTP requests made to fetch those files.

I would suggest to use [Yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) which is a great extension for [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) that analyzes web pages and suggests ways to improve their performance.