# Multiple CSS or Single CSS file (For mobile purpose)

Tags: css, mobile

I understand that there are duplicates in this question, but I am opening up this question to a different playing field in today's context. There are two stackoverflow duplicates here.

[Single huge .css file vs. multiple smaller specific .css files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files)
[Multiple css files or one big css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757318/multiple-css-files-or-one-big-css-file)

Firstly, I do understand that multiple css files means multiple http request etc. But does a single css file make searching for data more difficult, (more processing power needed?)

In mobile context, is today's mobile 4G network sufficient for this to make the problem almost obselete. Either way, the question boils down to processor competence vs network performance.

I would like a general sense of how do you guys built your applications for mobile considerations

Comment: CSS does not search for data - it matches HTML selectors, which has nothing to do with CSS file size.

Answer (score 0):

A single css file does not require more processing power than multiple files. You should always try to reduce HTTP requests when possible, and combining multiple CSS files into a single file is an extremely easy way to reduce HTTP requests. In a mobile network context, remember that there are huge parts of the world that still don't have access to 4G speeds.