# google app engine templates and style sheets

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine, templates

So I have come up with the following style sheet in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8FNZE/2/ and I want to use that as the base of a bunch of following web pages.  My questions is can I use that page with the included stylesheet affecting only that HTML that is there and then for the child templates can I have a different CSS doc that affects only the child's HTML.  I am using Jinja2 and coding the app with python.

If that won't work should I just make a big stylesheet with information for all of the pages or what would the best way to go about it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files) post which details the pros and cons of using a single stylesheet versus multiple ones.

Comment: Great link for pros and cons. From the link I take it that it will all work properly if I use the one main style sheet from the parent and use child sheets as well it just might be a tad slower.

Comment: Yes, clifgray, essentially you have to balance performance versus ease of maintenance.