# dynamic CSS - multiple stylesheets vs single dynamic css (rendering performance)

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, stylesheet, styling

I'm writing website supporting "plugins" as external "displays" (custom full screen HTML content, managed by website engine and js driver provided by client, which uses provided by engine API to interact with other clients) driven by custom js, html and css. Themes will be organised into external repositories, there would be .theme file containing list of files included by theme so that they'll be loaded and stored in IndexedDB for faster, local usage - as well as css rules for client HTML

The point is that clients are accessing and changing css rules to adjust responsive layout. Changing text of primary layout css causes reloading style and loss of all changes in rules done by js. Clients are loaded dynamically so theese changes may happen anytime.

So I need to choose one of following options:

1. use CSS text modules - after loading new client - primary css text would be extended by adding new content (innerHTML) and calling cssreload function on all clients
2. use multiple stylesheets and provide API for clients to modify only it's own stylesheet to avoid reloading after new clients injection.

Which one would achieve better performance? Average numbe of clients is like 10 - 20.
Is there maybe another, better solution i didn't think of?
Multiple stylesheets seem to be more lightweight (at least to me) as they don't need js reloading, however I'm not sure if such a high number of different stylesheets won't cause heavy performance drop on site rerendering comparing to solution with single enormous stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

From everything I've read, best practice is to have one stylesheet instead of multiple, unless it can't be avoided.  This is because, these days, the slowest part of web browsing is making multiple requests.  If you can load all CSS in one request, even if the file is huge, that is *generally* faster than loading multiple CSS files.

There's a [great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files) and explanation on this.  It might be worth a read.

Comment: css is loaded from localStorage, not web, website is downloading content on first run, it's offline webapp, It's all about cpu performance, not networking that's why answer is not that obvious at least to me

Comment: Ah, I misread your question.  It's probably a wash, but I still err on the side of fewer requests.