# Why shouldn't i put all stylesheets in Public folder in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, stylesheet

I'm a newbie at Reactjs. When converting HTML to JSX Component, i notice that developers always device CSS files into smaller part and import it in JSX Component. 
I wonder why they not aggregate into 1 file and import it in Puclic folder.
Thanks in advance for your help! :D

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files

Comment: For the same reason it's a good idea to have lots of smaller JavaScript files.  Much more maintainable / composable code.  And then leave the bundler to bundle into single large files.

Comment: thanks `muskrat_` and `Keith`

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your react project using the cli tool "create-react-app" it is using webpack as module bundler.

Webpack doesn't read anything in the public folder it only reads from src folder so it is advised to placed the css/stylesheets in your src folder.

Comment: Whether i could put them into index.css in src folder?