# Is the 7-1-pattern bad to performance?

Tags: performance, sass, lighthouse

I was used to using the [7-1-pattern](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5625786-produce-maintainable-css-with-sass/5723581-use-the-7-1-pattern-for-a-manageable-codebase) to structure my Sass codebase.

Now I started analyzing my project with Google Lighthouse, and basically it tells me that I should removed my unused CSS. The unused CSS however is there because I include my `main.sass`, which includes all styles independently from the page I'm on.

How do you guys usually deal with this? Page-specific imports (breaking the 7-1-pattern) or are there other tweaks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single huge .css file vs. multiple smaller specific .css files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336302/single-huge-css-file-vs-multiple-smaller-specific-css-files)

Comment: Not really, basically everyone over there suggests that a large file is a good way to go, but nobody talks about performance and unused css

Comment: You should read all the answer, I like specially these one who talk about Http2...